# Unique is Cheap

Tags: string, self-scoring

Write a function or program that determines the *cost* of a given string, where

- the cost of each character equals the number of how many times the character has occurred up to this point in the string, and
- the cost of the string is the sum of its characters' costs.

#### Example

For an input of `abaacab`, the cost is computed as follows:

```
a b a a c a b
1   2 3   4    occurrence of a
  1         2  occurrence of b
        1      occurrence of c
1+1+2+3+1+4+2 = 14
```

Thus the cost for the string `abaacab` is 14.

#### Rules

- **The score of your submission is the cost of your code as defined above**, that is your submission run on its own source code, with a **lower** score being better.
- Your submission should work on strings containing printable ASCII-characters, plus all characters used in your submission.
- Characters are case-sensitive, that is `a` and `A` are different characters.

#### Testcases

```
input -> output
"abaacab" -> 14
"Programming Puzzles & Code Golf" -> 47
"" -> 0
"       " -> 28
"abcdefg" -> 7
"aA" -> 2
```

#### Leaderboard

```js
var QUESTION_ID=127261,OVERRIDE_USER=56433;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px} /* font fix */ body {font-family: Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;} /* #language-list x-pos fix */ #answer-list {margin-right: 200px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: How do program flags such as `-n` for Perl count towards the score? It traditionally counts as 1 byte because the edit distance between the standard `perl -e` and `perl -ne` is 1, but for this challenge, will the `n` count for the purposes of counting duplicates?

Comment: @ValueInk Yes, I think counting the `n` is the fairest option.

Comment: I really wish there was a brainfuck solution to this challenge.

Comment: +1 for **The score of your submission is the cost of your code**

Comment: Is the input as char-array allowed instead of String?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Sure.

Comment: @Peter1807, wish granted!

Comment: cost of a character is defined as `how often this character has already occurred in the string`, i'd probably changing to `how many times the character has occurred up to this point` to make it clearer that the first use costs 1, not 0

Comment: @undergroundmonorail Thanks, I added your suggested wording.

Comment: Is the leaderboard supposed to be unsorted?

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Do you mean the language names in the winners-by- language section? I wouldn't mind if they were sorted, though I don't really know how the snippet works as I just copied it from an other challenge. Feel free to fix it if you know how.

Comment: Alas, I have no idea, except that e.g. the [golf you a quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69/golf-you-a-quine-for-great-good/) leaderboard is sorted.

Answer (score 84):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), score 4

```
&=Rz
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X802qOr/f/XEpMTE5MQkdQA)

#### Explanation

Consider input `'ABBA'` as an example.

```
&=   % Implicit input. Matrix of all equality comparisons
     % STACK: [1 0 0 1;
               0 1 1 0;
               0 1 1 0;
               1 0 0 1]
R    % Upper triangular part
     % STACK: [1 0 0 1;
               0 1 1 0;
               0 0 1 0;
               0 0 0 1]
z    % Number of nonzeros. Implicitly display
     % STACK: 6
```

Comment: Are you a linear algebra professor?

Comment: @carusocomputing Actually a mobile communications professor. My tendency to use matrices comes from years of programming in Matlab

Comment: Neat! Is Matlab big in that area? I've never really looked into GSM or anything like it.

Comment: I joined this community just to commend you on this brilliant solution!

Comment: @Wboy Thanks, I feel honored :-) And welcome to PPCG!

Comment: @carusocomputing Matlab is a very common tool/language in engineering in general. It's good at numerical computation: linear algebra, signal processing, and the like. And being an interpreted language it's very easy to use

Answer (score 17):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), score 49

```python
lambda S:sum(1+S.count(C)for[C]in	S)/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYu9CoMwFEZnfYrLHUrE0lJHwSmDq5DROqQxsYH8SKLQ@vJppGf7ON9Zv9vbuyYJP8vumdBw@5o5sDbuljxqdhN@dxuhlfJhpJN2BavuDSb5kQJVh/UZlllCBO1gPOcVcAh@Cdxa7RYY9uMwMsIFaJbQe6MwX@APTm1ZrEG7DRSJVfoB)

There's a tab after `in`.

Score breakdown:

- +27 for 27 unique chars
- +16 for 8 double chars: `()Camnou`
- +6 for 1 tripled char: `S`

Comment: Use a tab instead of a space to save a byte.

Comment: @mbomb007 Just had the same idea :-)

Comment: @mbomb007 Hah, that's a genius trick :-)

Comment: @mbomb007 that's just tabs vs. spaces war inside golfed code

Comment: Wouldn't it be +5 for `S` three times? i.e. +2 for the second, and +3 for the third.

Comment: @BrianJ I mean +3 over the raw character count, which counts 3 bytes for the 3 copies while the score counts 6.

Comment: @xnor Ah, of course. I understand the math now.

Comment: I was going to suggest using a form feed (which is also permitted whitespace in Python syntax), but you don't have any more whitespace to replace.

Comment: Clearly form feeds are the best characters to use for indenting code.

Answer (score 8):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), score:  <s>113</s>   <s>103</s>   <s>100</s>   <s>96</s>  91

*Thanks to @ugoren, @CalculatorFeline, @gastropner, @l4m2, and @JS1 for their tips.*

```c
g(char*s){int y[238]={};while(*s)*y-=--y[*s++];*y/=1;}
```

Initializes an array of zeros, then uses the ASCII values of the characters in the string as indices to that array to keep track of the number of instances of each character in the string.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY2xDoIwFEV3vuKFRNMWG6MuRsJgHFxJHIGhlFKaQDFFYwrh2xFwMjEM3vHe887jVHI@DBLxghnS4E7pB9hofzgmQdf7r0KVAo09sTSg1Eak8bzEJ3Yb7Px@mOCKKY2w0zkw5m7GKkfujddGnGCVxTrW7gYkcv974WLsO1/qyfkxspQxztIZ@U2EppaGVZXSEsJn25aigTVc6kzAtS7zhcuFCT5ZIFjKM5HLJeI8j/3wBg)

Comment: Suggestion: Use variable names that aren't used in keywords, like `z`,`x`,`c`.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline `char` includes `c`...

Comment: Oh right...well, you get the point.

Comment: Also, you only need a 127 element array (`\x7f` is not printable) and please add an explanation.

Comment: You need `return z`. Replacing it with `z=z` might work on some platforms and without optimization.

Comment: `z-=-` saves 2 points.

Comment: Better - `z+=--y` and return `-z`.

Comment: @ugoren It says `C (gcc)` for a reason. If it fails on your system, please post specs.

Comment: Also, can confirm that this does not work on OSX fake `gcc`.

Comment: Also, it seems that on my machine, you can drop the `z=` part. Confirmed on TIO as well.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline Which `z=` do you mean? Dropping the latter instance of it doesn't work on TIO (at least for me), and dropping the former instance works but then the function can only be called once.

Comment: Forgot about the "must be callable multiple times" rule. Ignore.

Comment: Late to the party, but this should be 96: `z;g(char*s){int y[238]={z=0};while(*s)z+=--y[*s++];z/=~0;}`

Comment: @gastropner Thanks!

Comment: ```g(char*s){int y[238]={};while(*s)*y+=--y[*s++];*y/=~0;}```

Comment: `g(char*s){int y[238]={};while(*s)*y-=--y[*s++];*y/=1;}`

Answer (score 8):

## T-SQL, score <s>775 579!</s> 580

```
declaRe @ char(876),@x int,@v int=0Select @=q+CHAR(9)from z X:seleCT @x=len(@),@=REPLACE(@,LEFT(@,1),''),@v+=(@x-LEN(@))*(@x-LEN(@)+1)/2IF LEN(@)>0GOTO X prINT @v-1
```

**EDIT**: Dropped a couple of variables, compacted a bit. Down to 16 `@` symbols instead of 22, that by itself reduces my score by a whopping 117 points!

Nice contest, I like the requirement to optimize for something besides total character count.

Input is via varchar field *q* in pre-existing table *z*, [per our IO rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341). The database containing this input table must be set to a *case-sensitive collation*.

Formatted:

```
declaRe @ char(876), @x int, @v int=0
Select @=q+CHAR(9)from z
X:
    seleCT @x=len(@)
          ,@=REPLACE(@,LEFT(@,1),'')
          ,@v+=(@x-LEN(@))*(@x-LEN(@)+1)/2
IF LEN(@)>0 GOTO X
prINT @v-1
```

SQL keywords aren't case sensitive, so I used mixed case to minimize the count of duplicate letters (*aaAA* generates a better/lower score than *aaaa*).

The main loop compares the length before and after stripping all instances of the first character out. That difference n*(n+1)/2 is added to a running total.

The SQL `LEN()` function annoyingly ignores trailing spaces, so I had to append a control character and subtract 1 at the end.

**EDIT**: Fixed a miscalculation of my own score by 2 points (issue with quoting quotes), reduced by 1 by changing casing of one `R`. Also working on a completely different strategy, I'll be posting that as its own answer.

Comment: At first I thought your score was `579! ≈ 8.22 x 10^1349`

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), score 6

```
;\ċ"⁸S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9865ki30qPGHcH/kdgA)

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), score <s>81</s> 78

*Saved 3 points thanks to @Arnauld*

```
s=>s.replace(d=/./g,z=>q+=d[z]=-~d[z],q=0)&&q
```

My original score-81 recursive solution:

```
f=([c,...s],d={})=>c?(d[c]=-~d[c])+f(s,d):0
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), score 42

```hs
f l=sum[1|c<-l,d<-c:l,d==c]/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYuxDoIwFEV/5aYxTBAjo6GTgys7YXiUFhvfa0kLC/Hfq/yA0znDOS/Kb8tcigPrvMtw@5iu4XruGnP/QWszXtsi5AM01uTDhguEVjgM6u@kaiiaiAxNp/YpLolEfFjQ78fBNqPCI84Wz8juTNRYvg)

Anonymizing `\l->` gives the same score.

Answer (score 7):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), score 34

```
s(O`.
M&!`^|(?<=(.))\1*
.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@/WMM/QY/LV00xIa5Gw97GVkNPUzPGUItLD48UAA)

#### Explanation

```
s(O`.
```

We start by sorting all the characters in the input so that identical characters are grouped together into a single run. The `s(` activates singleline mode for all stages (i.e. makes `.` match linefeeds).

```
M&!s`^|(?<=(.))\1*
```

The goal is to turn a run of **n** characters into **T<sub>n</sub>** characters (the **n**th triangular number) because that's the score of the occurrences of this character. To do so, we find overlapping matches. In particular, for each **i** in **[1,n]**, we're going to include **i-1** characters in the match. We get all those matches due to the overlapping flag `&`. That gives us **n*(n-1)/2 = T<sub>n-1</sub> = T<sub>n</sub> - n** characters just from the matches. But the match stage will join these with linefeeds, which are **n** linefeeds for **n** matches. There's only one problem. There won't be a linefeed after the last match, so the overall number of characters in the output is one less than we need. We fix this by also matching the beginning of the input, which gives us a single leading linefeed if there is at least one other match.

```
.
```

Finally, we just count how many characters there are in the string.

Answer (score 6):

### Haskell, score <s>52</s> 51

```
f(a:b)=1+sum[1|c<-b,c==a]+f b;f _=0
```

There's a tab between `f` and `_`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY49C8IwGAZn/RUPQUSpgl3VTA5du6vImzRpg/koSbsU/3t0zuJ4xw03UHora3PWOzqLPa@rNLt7/ZHXozhIzulZaYiLXr34KTsyHhxdwBrAGI2fsIEGI0EkSbBCtzH0kZwzvkc7L4tVCVvcQqfQBKvLvOQ/S4/p98TyFw)

The value of the empty string is 0. The value of the string s, where `a` is the first char and `b` the rest of the string is 1 plus the occurrences of `a` in `b` plus a recursive call with b.

Answer (score 5):

### [J](http://jsoftware.com/), score 16

```
1#.,@(*+/\"1)&=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P03B1krBUFlPx0FDS1s/RslQU832f2pyRr5CmoJ6YlJiYnJikjoXTABNofp/AA)

### Explanation

```
1#.,@(*+/\"1)&=
              =  Self-classify: bit matrix of equality between input
                 and its unique elements.
     (      )&   Apply verb in parentheses to it:
       +/\         running sums
          "1       of each row
      *            multiplied with original matrix.
                 This causes the i'th 1 on each row to be replaced by i.
   ,@            Flatten the resulting matrix
1#.              and interpret as a base-1 number, computing its sum.
```

Using `1#.` instead of `+/@` for the sum saved a few points, and `&` could be used instead of `@` in a monadic context to save one more.
The repeated `1` costs me one extra point, but I haven't been able to get rid of it.

Comment: "later" *waits a quarterday*

Comment: @CalculatorFeline 10 hours later is still later. :P

Comment: Let's make it a sesquisemiday now.

Comment: I personally use [this format](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BOj5u/w2V9XQcNLS09WOUDDXVbP9rcqUmZ@QrpCmoJyYlJiYnJqnDBdCUqv8HAA) for TIO answers in order to reflect an accurate byte count in the code section, maybe you would want to use it

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), score: 67 <s>83</s> <s>95</s> <s>128</s>

*-61 thanks to top tips from Giuseppe*

```r
function(x,y=table(utf8ToInt(x)))y%*%{y+1}/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZFNa8MwDIbv@xUmrIvUFkp6Gowcxg5jh0EPu5Ue7MTODI4dbAfqlv72zIn3wTpoJ4yNhJ5XL7IdlGSW2gB5y/27qV2ON6IcRK8rL42G/TKUnjLFoffi/s28aA97RAyz@ewYFsVptR4E5JRRWlE2wpBvrGksbVupG7LpDwfFHbkjT6bm5NkokZrSTVKkhLKq5qL5TB7T@yqdG0/XyamQ/VhD17cAurTRnTPWA1fgvHWdktHkMo6IcatwtZ6DXhSI2bnA8Sr8MM7Q3wqnixK/@e222O3@p/G14zMDExgiOG36L3j9bzIcPgA)

The string is split using `utf8ToInt` and each ascii value is counted `table`.  The the result is calculated using doing a matrix multiplication `%*%` over that at itself + 1 and finally halfed.

Comment: use `table` instead of `rle`; you can get rid of the `sort` as well (and you don't have to index `[[1]]` into the result of `strsplit`)

Comment: @Giuseppe Thanks a lot.  I didn't even think of table, will incorporate soon.

Comment: I think you can save a few more bytes by using a different variable name instead of `n` (since it's in `function` twice) and also changing `(n+1)` to `{n+1}`

Comment: [score:67](https://tio.run/##jZFNa8MwDIbv@xUmrIvUFkp6Gowcxg5jh0EPu5Ue7MTODI4dbAfqlv72zIn3wTpoJ4yNhJ5XL7IdlGSW2gB5y/27qV2ON6IcRK8rL42G/TKUnjLFoffi/s28aA97RAyz@ewYFsVptR4E5JRRWlE2wpBvrGksbVupG7LpDwfFHbkjT6bm5NkokZrSTVKkhLKq5qL5TB7T@yqdG0/XyamQ/VhD17cAurTRnTPWA1fgvHWdktHkMo6IcatwtZ6DXhSI2bnA8Sr8MM7Q3wqnixK/@e222O3@p/G14zMDExgiOG36L3j9bzIcPgA "R – Try It Online"). Some variation on this might make it possible to reduce the score further.

Comment: @Giuseppe ... I should have re read it .  whoops

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), score 5

```
ĠJ€ẎS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///IAq9HTWse7uoL/o/MAQA)

Thanks to [Leaky Nun](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48934/leaky-nun) for -2 (previously on [his answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127265/41024))

Comment: Ahhh I didn't notice this question fast enough.

Comment: @LeakyNun p.s. you're not always a ninja, nor anyone is

Comment: Really? I don't think so.

Comment: Score 5: [`ĠJ€ẎS`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///IAq9HTWse7uoL/o/MAQA)

Comment: @LeakyNun As promised...yeah, the credit is there :)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), score 6

```
{γ€gLO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/@tzmR01r0n38kZgA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), score 6

1 byte thanks to isaacg.

```
+F/V._
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2BF%2FV._&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22s%2B0%2FV._%22%0A%22abaacab%22%0A%22Programming+Puzzles+%26+Code+Golf%22%0A%22%22%0A%22+++++++%22%0A%22abcdefg%22%0A%22aA%22&debug=0)

### How it works

```
+F/V._
+F/V._QQ  implicit input
  /V      vectorize count: for each element in the first argument,
                           count the number of occurrences of the
                           second argument:
    ._Q       all prefixes of input
       Q      input
+F        fold (reduce) on +, base case 0.
```

Comment: `s+0` is the same as `+F`.

Comment: Good!  The best I could do is `usaShHGrScQ1 8Z` for 16.  Can you add an explanation?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma I've added an explanation.

Comment: `s/LQ` is score 4, does this use features that postdates the challenge?

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), score: <s>14 12</s> 11

```
$+/@,2!1#.=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/pfZmulUGtloGBl8F9FW99Bx0jRUFnP9r8mV0q@gnqarZ66ThlXanJGvkKagnpiUmJicmKSOlwgoCg/vSgxNzczL10hoLSqKie1WEFNwTk/JVXBPT8nDaEQwVKAALhA2X8A)

Comment: Clever use of `$`.

Comment: Nice.  Slight 11 byte variation: `1#.2!1+1#.=`

Comment: @Jonah Reusing glyphs results in a penalty

Comment: ah, missed that part.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), score of 7

```
ċÐ€QRFS
```

Explanation:

```
   Q    get unique letters
ċÐ€     count the occurences of each letter in the original string
    R   [1..n] for n in list of frequencies
     F  flatten list
      S sum
        (implicit output)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9I9@EJj5rWBAa5Bf9H4QEA)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 4):

## C, 60 bytes, score <strike>108</strike> 95

```
g(char*s){int y[256]={},z=0;while(*s)z-=--y[*s++];return z;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pY3dDoIgAIVfhdnaAKFlW92Qvohx4QCBTakh2sT57AbP0N3Z@fmOoFqI42SdGGapwHMK0r4vpjk0FKbzeEKbdQGs7e3@4PW2k1hf2dfYQcGURVpTurZ4KkvOvAqzdyCy/Rg762DedV4LkkEA46SXROthNpsKfXxq9LA4y5criM720lYcoQT46/4H)

Usually pre- and post-increment operators are great for code golf, but they really hurt on this challenge!

EDIT: By subtracting negative counts instead of adding positive ones, I saved a whole bunch of score. Replacing `for()` with `while()` eliminated a semicolon as well.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), score  <s>61 56 53 46</s>  44

```perl6
(1 X..*.comb.Bag.values).flat.sum
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##hY9PT8MwDMXv@RRPY1o2NEUMTQMp4gAcuO7AgdvkpklXKSFV3UzaEJ@99I@gXBC@2P7p2c@ubO13bWKL004ZLcIZCxO5wUO73OBNqWtlYsjUExXqRD5ZXinnqVGcQqsF0xny9WhhYm5RNmy9w5EYhGFLdJDrsZT/7pNaVKkTdllwypCXXPnOYIn5ASt8CKD3U1V38xryD5/5QYtPIb6HJWVEhjKpcYXN9ofP9nUsagqhfC@wT5eLt4wFnvs/XqJ3s16/vZv0A7iZeowx4Nv7iVNmcuuKgf8ap8dR2X4B)

```perl6
{sum flat 1 X.. .comb.Bag.values}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##hY9Pa8MwDMXv/hSPrtQbFLOO0g7CDtsOu/aww25Fduw0YM8higtt6WfP8octu4zpIunHk55U2dpv2sQWx40ymQgnLEzkBk/thVOA89RghQ@loEwMWr1QoY7kk@Vry3SCfD9YmJhblA1b73AgBmHYER3kcizlv9tkJqrUCbssOGnkJVe@M7jFfI87XATQ@6mqu3gJ@YfPfJ@JqxDfw5I0kSEtM9xgtf7hs10di5pCKD8L7NL57C1jgdf@j7fo3azXr7eTfgD3U48xBvzwOHHSJreuGPivcXoele0X)

```perl6
{sum flat 1 X.. values(.comb.Bag)}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##hY9Pa8MwDMXv/hSPrtQtFLOO0g5CD9sOu/aww25Fcew0YNchigtt6WfP8octu4zpIunHk55UmsptmsgG543SifAXzHTgGrvmxtHDOqqxwqdSOJOLhudKB5@qV8oX94bpAvlxNNAhMyhqNs7iSAxCvyRYyOVQyv/XyUSUsVW2WXBMkRVcutZhjukBC9wE0Bmqsr15CfmH0fSQiLsQ38OSUiJNqUzwgNX6h0/2Vcgr8r445djH69UZxgxv3SPvwdlJp19vR30PHsceQ/T46XnklOrM2Lznv8bpZVA2Xw)

```perl6
{[+] flat	1	X.. values(.comb.Bag)}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##hY9PawIxEMXP5lM8VIyihFrEFhYP2kOvHnoolCKTbLIuZM2y2Qgqfvbt/qHdXkrnMjM/3sybyXVh11XwGue1UBHLLpgo50tsqtvH/BPGUjlYDt6FwJls0H4qlMuk2FEyu1eeLuBvRw3lYo209NoaHMmD0C5xBnzRlfz/dTxieaiVdWY@SMSpz23tMMX4gBluDGgMRV7fvAD/w2h8iNidse9hTpJIkeQRRliufvhwX7ikoCxLTwn24Xq12mOCl@aRV2fNsNGvnnp9Cx76Hl20@PG55yRVrE3S8l/jtO2U1Rc)

```perl6
{[+] flat	1	X.. values(bag
.comb)}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##hY9PawIxEMXP5lM8rBilEmoRW1g8lB569dCDIEUm2WRdyJplsxFU/Ozr/qFdL9K5zMyPN/Nmcl3YZRW8xnEpVMSyE8bK@RKr6rJ9/oGxVA7mg40QOJIN2k8kJUwol8nptfJ0Av/eaygXa6Sl19ZgTx6Edokz4LOu5P@v4xHLQ62sM/NBIk59bmuHCUY7THFhQGMo8vrmGfgDo9EuYlfGfoc5SSJFkkd4wnzxx4frwiUFZVl6SLAO57PVHmN8No98OWuGjX7x1utb8NL36KLFr@89J6libZKW343TR6esbg)

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), score ∞ (I mean, 209)

```cs
b=>b.Distinct().Select(z=>{var w=b.Count(p=>p==z);return w*(w+1)/2;}).Sum()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVA9a8MwEN39K44MQeqHTEqggysvLu3SQiBDZ1mRg0CWEn3E1MG/3ZWMm0K7ZOgbjuM@3r173N1zY8UIEcFJvYftp/OiJW9SH4ssS3WumHOwsWZvWTtVzlNMcJ55yeFk5A7emdQIX1o/Qwkz7UvQ/Ml5Gy/dgdS@hAZoNta0rMmzdF5q7hEmW6FETHpank/MQkdrUpmgPTrQ8kBpjwsrfLAauhvU3a5w/lAMcSu0CI@z6l@HK6OdUYJ8WOlFfE6gBi1YzRhn9QLjAvIcVuurN2c32uTYJvS9Eg6WUJmdgFejmm/G9ePVjH/d/0dTkp6LkmHKhvEL)

The score includes the following:

```cs
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: I know it's been a while, but you can change `return w*(w+1)/2` to `return-~w*w/2` (score 196). EDIT: You can create a port of [my Java 8 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142701/52210) for a score of **149**: `using System.Linq;b=>{int[]x=new int[256];return\nb.Select(z=>++x[z]).Sum();}` [Try it online.](https://tinyurl.com/yachc866)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: I got your solution down to a score of 111: `b=>{var x=new int[256];return\nb.Sum(z=>++x[z]);}`

Comment: @raznagul (_*half year old response incoming*_) **109** if you change the second space to a tab. ;) [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##pZHPT8IwFMfP7q944WBWkREJ6mF2F4xeNCHh4AE4tFsHTbYW247ByPzXZ4vDEDQh0Vvz8vr98Xmx7sVSsabQXCxgstWG5cELF@8hQL8PY6IMyBTMkgHdGmaXC2GAiAT0UhZZApQBSRKWgJH7Le3kvDgjWsNYyYUi@c4D0IYYHsNa8gReCRc@clM4OD4VIn7QRtkQ18CFiSAF3FAc7dZEwQYLVl7Y8XRwezcPFTOFEh4NJkXuVzjqdjfTao7CunGK4bHuSAotMxa8KW6YrcX81O8QSkhMaAeh0HW8GZ790RbJHaNxUVUZ03AJI5kweJZZelAa3p9V@snZlqTBI9eGi9j4KJiwjNlH1XYvMbVKFrq/wtEK4wq1/Xsf5VXZH4Q12nNALsTf7HeO7HwPGU4gzwQ9CtSC/vIL6384fl91Zn5zPLlra1R7dfMJ)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen (another half year old response incoming) 49 with the interactive compiler, and I think it won't ever get below 48. I find it odd how the more golfed C# answers get, the more readable they always seem to become. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lc9BC4IwGMbxu5/ixUMollJYHZYSCHXpIHjoIB3mmjJwG2yzbF/eLKpj1P39/3heomdEs6G4aUN5uOsE2WijmGimwIRJoYZkqJK0CouOezZJg6Av7clHF6ygTwS9OuNZuViuTmhALyWTQsuWhkfFDD0wQb3ac3GFMcGV6/sIogjmsfPM4ZM73@pcyUZhzsdhkHfWtlTDBDJ5prCXbf1W4/U/6tb97bOHPtwB "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

### PowerShell, score 64

```
$z=@{}
$ARGS|% getE*|%{$u+=($Z.$_+=1)};$U
```

(Score is based on a single linefeed newline, which isn't Windows standard but does work in PS).

```
PS C:\> D:\unique-is-cheap.ps1 (gc D:\unique-is-cheap.ps1 -raw)
64
```

- Hashtable counter `@{}`
- Iterate through the letters; `$args` is an array of parameters - in this case the input string makes it a single item array; `|%` does a foreach loop over the items, and uses the `getE*` shortcut to match the `GetEnumerator()` string method and call it to turn the string into a character stream.
- `|%` loop over the characters and increment their hashtable entry, add it to a running total. The `($x+=1)` form with parens both modifies the variable and outputs the new value for use.
- Output the running total.

(When I first wrote it, it was `$c=@{};$t=0;[char[]]"$args"|%{$c[$_]++;$t+=$c[$_]};$t` with a score of 128, and felt like it wouldn't go much lower. Halving it to 64 is quite pleasing).

Comment: [61 pts/ 38 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X6XK1qG6lkvFMcg9uEZVIT21xFWrRrVapVTbVltbJUpPJb7WWiX0////6sSpVAcA) by messing with the increment

Comment: [59 pts/36 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X6XK1qG6lkvFMcg9uEZVoUSrska1WqVU21ZbWyVKTyW@1lol9P///@rEqFMHAA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## Java 10, score: <s>149</s> <s>138</s> <s>137</s> <s>134</s> <s>133</s> <s>130</s> <s>103</s> <s>102</s> <s>101</s> 100

(**Bytes: <s>72</s> <s>73</s> <s>74</s> <s>75</s> <s>64</s> <s>62</s> 61**) <s>Bytes go up, but score goes down. :D</s>

```java
x->{int j=0,q[]=new int[256];for(var    C:x)j+=++q[C];return
j;}
```

-28 score (and -11 bytes) thanks to *@Nevay*.
-1 score (and -2 bytes) thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*.
-1 score (and -1 byte) by converting Java 8 to Java 10.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##lZE/b4MwEMXn8ilOGSojGlRVaociKkUMnRpFykgYDmMoFOzkbGj@iM9OTeiYSsWyhzvfe/eTXoUdLqvsa@A1ag0fWMqLA1BKIyhHLmA9ltcGcMY/keIEtBvYZm@fvdqgKTmsQUIIw3H5dhlnq/Dx4RAnoRTfozZ@en5JglwR65DuotejW3mh5x3iKAlImJakUwX9EEyW@zatreWvc6fKDBoLxraGSllYAHQnqu1JG9H4qjX@3n6ZWjLpc7bAFJFjuvCNiizyighPzHWv2H@rNqQKwqaxO2DTns@10HAPkcoEvKs6n@k2cxymM1OFKc9EXsxVrWYK/pPqztyKdSdtrje39U4//AA)

```java
x->{                     // Method with character-array parameter and integer return-type
  int j=0,               //  Result-integer, starting at 0
      q[]=new int[256];  //  Integer-array with 256 times 0
  for(var   C:x)         //  Loop over the characters of the input array
    j+=++q[C];           //   Raise the value in the array by 1,
                         //   and then add it to the result-integer
  return                 //  Return 
  j;}                    //         the result
```

Comment: You can remove the `~` if you use `j=0` and `return-j;` (133).

Comment: 103: `x->{int[]q=new int[256];return\nx.chars().map(v->++q[v]).sum();}`

Comment: @Nevay 103 actually, when I use `j` instead of `u` (`return` contains `u`) and a new-line and tab instead of the spaces. EDIT: Hehe, you've edited right when I made this comment. :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 45 bytes, Score: 77

Inspired by the MATL solution:

```julia
f(w)=sum(UpperTriangular([z==j for z=w,j=w]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/8/TaNc07a4NFcjtKAgtSikKDMxL700J7FII7rK1jZLIS2/SKHKtlwny7Y8VlPzf3ByflGqgq1CQVFmXolGmoYSSdqVgCYAAA)

A less pretty solution, using counts:

[Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), score: 82

```julia
F(w)=sum(l->[l+1]l/2,count(x->x==i,w)for i=Set(w))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@//fTaNc07a4NFcjR9cuOkfbMDZH30gnOb80r0SjQteuwtY2U6dcMy2/SCHTNji1BKhY839BUSZQ1k1DiXS9SkDtAA)

Thanks to Guiseppe for pointing out the scoring and for tips.
These comments helped me loads.

Comment: _The score of your submission is the cost of your code_, which I think is 135.

Comment: I don't know Julia very well but I think you can reduce the score to [110](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/8/TcNR07a4NFejQtdOo0LbUFOrQt9IByQQnWlrm6WQll@kkGnrqJNlW5qXWViaClQeq2Ooqfm/oCgzr0QjTUOJXBOUgIYAAA) by switching some variable names and removing a set of parentheses. If returning a single-element vector is allowed, then you can replace `(x+1)` with `[x+1]` to further reduce the score.

Comment: You can save a score by changing the second space to a tab or  new-line: [**score 104**](https://tinyurl.com/ycstk3yq). And @Giuseppe tip of using `[x+1]` instead of `(x+1)` lowers it to a [score of 98](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/8/TaNc07a4NFcjR9cuOkfbMDZH30gHxI@usrXNVkjLL@Kssi3XybYtzcvMzwMqjtUx1NT8X1CUmVeikaahRJ5@JaARAA).

Comment: The second approach doesn't accept the empty string. It could be reduced to [63 points](https://tio.run/##jVDbSsNAEH12v@KwFdnVNbalEAkmUERFUCi0b7UPm2RTIpuk5AKbIn32W/wsfyRut@izAwPDmTNnZs57p3PpD8PBhE1XMJse88KQme/PL8OF4d5H1F9H6/5qsulvpnzY1XnZ6pLRlWraJqCctMcCIdbkjMpYykTGFGGEyUxYZFFX21oWRV5usej2e60aXOC@ShWeKp055sy3zBHY6mG5wuP8@WXJQV1nLGA1cAqHTG@F25OkKts6xHfA/NQVZEPIGr9X6p1MGb2jl0bMxlyARgGowMFwZFUNg7xEltdN6zH3BocdH43w2jUtYoVClp3Uuke3S2Wr0oAk9vKQUvpfwyyV/Hn2Vi6TqlYBztnhKMStfcMP) in Julia 0.7.

Comment: Adding a special case for the empty string brings the [score to 83](https://tio.run/##lVDBSsQwFDybr3hkRRKNtbsUVoqpiAdPwoLe1j2kbVoqaVrSFtJFevZb/Cx/pKZZ9O6DB8O8ecMw74OqxHaeJ8st5xjfh3E31MRtQALOif3@/LKUWRp8JON1sh@v1ofxZkPn1lS6V5rgV9n1XYwp6hcAHPboDItUiEykGHgC64g5Zmea0oi6rnQJu@F4VLKDC3hscglPjSq8MtouSg9DBg7CaTyzuWXeOMtlUXrGq8XD6crQAaE9/MZSrcgJvsOXlkUhZYCTGDCDyVIoGgMWKg1FZbo@ID43Bfe@WsHz0PWQSqiFHoRSIwxtLnqZxyhzUV1B@L9NuRf0V9abfskaI2M4J9NiSF1v8w8).

Answer (score 3):

### F#, score <strike>120</strike> 118

```
let j z=Seq.countBy id z|>Seq.sumBy(fun x->List.sum[0..snd x])
```

-2 thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pc/NioMwFAXgvU9xCLQojNL9TLPoMHQzC6FL6yLVKBlMYvMzVOm720RhXmB2h8vHufd2Nm@04csycIcfzMcLvxeN9sqdJogW85PGifXyNKWdV3jk9FtYFyfVoSisavGos6X6@FLOTKUWytE6iW2SCQVm@l8cE1SEvIOwG2MNu8VYGt0bJqVQPUo/zwO32ONTtxxnPXSR/O8kUid4UkQq2YhVCjV6h5wiXdNbqF9Dlv1Z4bjZ8MiEsQEnwGjCW50C2dmr2wkSgHUbyJDGhVsONYflBQ)

Takes a `string` as an input. `Seq.countBy` pairs each distinct character with its count (`id` is the identity function) so you end up with a collection like `'a' = 4, 'b' = 2` etc.

The `Seq.sumBy` takes the count for every letter and sums all the numbers from `0` to the count for that letter. So if `'a' = 4` the collection would be `0, 1, 2, 3, 4` which summed together is `10`. Then `Seq.sumBy` sums all those totals.

Comment: You can lower your score by 2 by changing `let q` to `let j`, since the `q` is already used in both `Seq`.

Answer (score 3):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), Score: 4

```
≠+´⊒
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4omgK8K04oqSCgo+4ouI4p+cRsKoIOKfqCLiiaArwrTiipIiCiJhYmFhY2FiIgoiUHJvZ3JhbW1pbmcgUHV6emxlcyAmIENvZGUgR29sZiIKIiIKIiAgICAgICAiCiJhYmNkZWZnIgoiYUEi4p+p)

The *occurrence count* builtin `⊒` calculates the cost of each character decremented by 1. To adjust for that we can either add 1 to each cost or add the length `≠` to the sum. The latter turns out to be a byte shorter.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), score <s>27</s> <s>18</s> <s>11</s> 10

*Reduced score by 7 thanks to @Adám by using a tradfn and using `1⊥` to sum the frequencies*

*Reduced score by 1 thanks to @rabbitgrowth by using a function instead*

```apl
1⊥{+/⍳≢⍵}⌸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/hR2wTDR11Lq7X1H/VuftS56FHv1tpHPTuAMurYxNUB)

Comment: Same method, score 11: [`1⊥{+/⍳≢⍵}⌸⍞`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM9ODm/KPW/4aOupdXa@o96Nz/qXPSod2vto54dj3rngRT8VwADsDouHOoA)

Comment: @Adám Thanks, the `1⊥` trick is really neat

Comment: Can't the `⍞` be omitted? It turns into a function, and it still works.

Comment: @rabbitgrowth Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Octave , score <s>77</s> 31 bytes

*same as @LuisMendo 's [MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127290/62451).

```matlab
@(a)nnz(triu(a==a'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQSNRMy@vSqOkKLNUI9HWNlFdU/N/mm1iXrE1V5qGEjZpJU2QTGJSYmJyYpKS5n8A)

Previous answer:

```matlab
@(d,g=accumarray(+d',1)-(0:254))sum(g(g>0));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQSNFJ902MTm5NDexqCixUkM7RV3HUFNXw8DKyNREU7O4NFcjXSPdzkBT0/p/mm1iXrE1V5qGEinalDRBOhKTEhOTE5OUNP8DAA)

Comment: You could probably save a point by ditching the semicolon. Couldn't test it as it doesn't seem to work with TIO.

Comment: @TomCarpenter Without `;` doesn't work. however such a lambda cab be used in `arrayfun`.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), score 15

```apl
+/1 1⍉+\∘.=⍨⍞
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKPdOb@45L@2vqGC4aPeTu2YRx0z9Gwf9a541DsPJPtfAQxAirgSkxITkxOTuJCEsOoDAA)

`⍞` get text input

`∘.=⍨` equality table with self

`+\` cumulative sum across

`1 1⍉` diagonal (lit. collapse both dimensions into dimension one)

`+/` sum

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), score <s>68</s> <s>45</s> 43

```
s`(.)(?<=((\1)|.)+)
$#3$*
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@/OEFDT1PD3sZWQyPGULNGT1Nbk0tF2VhFi8sQryQA) Link shows score. Edit: Thanks to @MartinEnder who saved 20 bytes by using overlapping matches instead of lookaheads and a further three bytes by grouping the stages so that the `s` flag only needs to be applied once. Saved a further two bytes by calculating the triangular number differently, avoiding the need for a sort.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, score 42

```
Total[#^2+#].5&@*CharacterCounts
```

**input**

> ["abcdefg"]

thanks to hftf
thanks to att

Comment: `Total[#(#+1)/2&@Counts@Characters@#]&` scores 54.

Comment: 42: `Total[#^2+#].5&@*CharacterCounts`

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp, score <s>286</s> <s>232</s> 222

```
(loop with w =(fill(make-list 128)0)as z across(read)sum(incf(elt w(char-code z))))
```

High-valued score due to the wordy syntax of builtin operators of Common Lisp.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tcwxCoAwDEDRqwSnZBDUycXDhFgxGG1pKgUvX72Ef358MfXUMGW9SkOLMUHVskOFBTc1w5OP0H@owDjNNBA7PMCSozvmwCv5faJesmGwAhVl59xLXAM89NWodT9suxc)

The ungolfed code:

```
(loop with w = (fill (make-list 128) 0)  ; create a list to count characters
   as z across (read)                   ; for each character of input
   sum (incf (elt w (char-code z))))     ; increase count in list and sum
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 45 bytes, Score 78

```php
WHILE($x=ORD($argn[$v++]))$y+=$$x-=-1;echo$y;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRoMCVWlSUXxRflFqQX1SSmZeuUeca7@cf4unsqmnNpZJYlJ5nqx7u4enjqqFSYesf5KIBFotWKdPWjtXUVKnUtlVRqdC11TW0Tk3OyFeptFa3/k@S@v//AQ)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 46 bytes, Score 79 Bytes

```php
WHILE(~$xy=$argn[$vz++])$su-=-$$xy+=1;echo$su;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRoMCVWlSUXxRflFqQX1SSmZeuUeca7@cf4unsqmnNpZJYlJ5nqx7u4enjqlGnUlFpCxaJVimr0taO1VQpLtW11VUBimvbGlqnJmfkA0Ws1a3/k6bh/38A)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 56 bytes, Score 92

```php
FOREAch(COUNT_CHARS($argn)as$z)WHILE($z)$y+=$z--;echo$y;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRoMCVWlSUXxRflFqQX1SSmZeuUeca7@cf4unsqmnNpZJYlJ5nq@7mH@TqmJyh4ewf6hcS7@zhGBSsAZbSTCxWqdIM9/D0cdUAMlQqtW1VqnR1rVOTM/JVKq3Vrf@Tq/X//695@brJickZqQA)

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 5 score <s>91</s> 83

Uses the `-p` flag which adds 2 because of the p in split.

```
$x=$_;$b+=++$a{$_}for(split//,$x);$_=$b
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Using your answer as a base and applying some techniques from the tips page, I managed to get your score down to 31: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lRttWW1slsVolvjYtv0hfTz@9tvr//wKs4v/yC0oy8/OK/@sWAAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online"). `$\` is automatically `print`ed after each call so we can use that to store the score and `/./g` returns a list of all chars in `$_`, which is cheaper than `split//`.

Comment: I know this is an old challenge, but you can cut the score even further: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lRttWW9shsVolvjYtv0hfTz@9tvr//wKs4v/yC0oy8/OK/@sWAAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 39 bytes, Score 69

```matlab
@(a)sum((b=hist(a,unique(1*a))).^2+b)/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc0xCgIxEEDRq0wjk9FVcVsRBI@gpQiT7AQDmrjJZGFPHxttrOw/7yenPElrR8NU6tMYe7iHooa7GsNYxeyWTESbW7@ytO3beOBY9v6VQ1RvcDHAGs4uZQGfMpzSINeI3WjwTxCJfrSLFAXHRQCRLbNjiwiaYJIc/Ay@RqchRX4EnT@zb0fU3g)

While there is another Octave answer, this one is entirely my own and a different approach, plus it scores less :).

The approach boils down to first finding the count (b) of each unique character, which is achieved using the histogram function. Then for each element we calculate the sum of 1 to b which is done using the formula `(b*(b+1))/2`. Then the individual sums are all summed into the final score.

In testing it seems brackets are really costly in the scoring because many are needed. I've optimised down from an initial score of about 88 by rearranging the questions to minimise the number of open/close brackets - hence we now do the /2 on the final total rather than individually, and also I've modified the formula to `(b^2+b)/2` as that requires fewer brackets.

Comment: Unfortunately this appears to fail on the empty string: `error: hist: subscript indices must be either positive integers less than 2^31 or logicals`

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), score 897

```
,[<<[[->+>-<<]>>[<]<[<]<[<]<[+<<]>>>>[>]>[->+>+<<]>[-<+>]<<<]<+[->>+<<]>>>[->+<]>[>]>,]<<[<]<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU5BDsIwDLvvFb1n5QVW3sA96qGdQJoYO2zs/cVpYUIiUhXHcVyXLc/r/ZgetY4GmEUVjUBSNSScTxpFUpM2TSMsQjSBEEJWPyoX@JbakVs3qO3U/ROn4brN62sP021ZQt7DejzLbRtMuzFicyEQdl6wGyId5Czwk0hCPZD0IG2Cl0dLQwhftaF3mrmv6C9weULL/y/n4tJD11xynnJ5Aw)

Ends on the cell with the correct value. Assumes a cell size larger than the score of the string, otherwise it'll wrap (got a little suspicious when the interpreter said the score was 188).

Comment: You might be able to change this to use one of the many binary-encoded brainfuck dialects that exist to lower your score...

Comment: [CompressedFuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/CompressedFuck) looks promising.

Comment: @EsolangingFruit That's like saying switching to Jelly may save some bytes on your Java answer... :P

Comment: @ConorO'Brien I'd argue that it's more akin to switching from a version of Jelly which must begin with the header `module Main where: import Jelly.Types; import Jelly.Builtins`. The problem being solved is the same, it's just more competitive. But I do see your point - switching languages is essentially switching competitions, so it's not really fair to ask someone to do that.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-x`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>9</s> <s>7</s> 6 points

```
ü mÊcõ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LXg&code=/CBtymP1&input=Ivwgbcpj9SI)

Comment: Not that hard to optimise for score when you can solve it using entirely unique characters, huh :P

Answer (score 2):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), score: 681

```
	s	=iNPUT
	Y	_table()
d	S	LEN(1) . x REM . S	:F(b)
	Y<X>	=y<X> + 1	:(D)
b	Z	_convert(Y,'aRrAy')
N	j	=J + 1
	G	_z[j,2]	:f(q)
	o	=o + g * G + g	:(N)
q	OUtpuT	_O / 2
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc5JawJBEAXg8@tfUTe7VRTF05QdCLiA6BhcwIXQOHESFJl2GUX989qO4ALGS71DPR7fJrKBXZROJ2ygZ/5XvycwhIknwSKUSkzRRbPqy4KiHO2pU2257MKryUC5YnnwAX1wlzJUgCcrSgQYwfzYaBeuYznMpiad9echpYSPOXTj0hOowxzH82zxG96vXLkhC23d64/SVL@km/KVWKHdj5fbHkyb8lQUYTRNnCZx8oOT3zn56jRPTv7HyXcnO6d@dPJrJ9@cOnGyc54B)

looks a bit scary, but SNOBOL matches identifiers case-insensitively, which dropped the score by around 100 points. Note that it requires a single line of input, so I've replaced `\n` with `;` in the input field (which is still valid SNOBOL).

The SNOBOL4 implementation on TIO allows for an additional 16 point golf, as `=` and `_` are [both allowable as the assignment operator](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/curr/doc/snobol4.1.html). How neat!

Answer (score 2):

## Rust, <del>265</del> 255 bytes. Score: <del>1459</del> 1161

```
fn main(){let mut z=String::new();std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut z);let Z=z.trim_right_matches(|x|x=='\r'||x=='\n');let mut q:Vec<u8>=Z.bytes().collect();q.sort();let(mut k,mut W,mut j)=(0,0u8,0);for Y in&q{if*Y==W{j+=1}else{j=1;W=*Y}k+=j}print!("{}",k)}
```

Ungolfed

```
fn main() {
    let mut input_string = String::new();
    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut input_string);
    let trimmed = input_string
        .trim_right_matches(|c| c == '\r' || c == '\n');
    let mut chars: Vec<u8> = trimmed.bytes().collect();
    chars.sort();
    let (mut total_score, mut last_char, mut last_score) = (0, 0u8, 0);
    for letter in &chars {
        if *letter == last_char {
            last_score += 1;
        } else {
            last_score = 1;
            last_char = *letter;
        }
        total_score += last_score;
    }
    print!("{}", total_score);
}
```

**Edit:** improved answer by renaming variables and altering code

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! In this challenge *the score of your submission is the cost of your code*, which I think is 1459.

Comment: Edited. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: This also means you can improve your score quite a bit by choosing characters as variable names which are not already contained in other keywords.

Comment: You're still using a lot of variable names that are characters used elsewhere. `jkqvxz` and most capitals are unused and would improve the score.

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), Score 9

```
½§+L(Σ´×=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9DeQ8u1fTTOLT605fB02////ycmIWAyAA)

**Explanation:**

This calculates the score as `sum_i (n_i^2 + n_i)/2`, where `i` is indexed arbitrarily across unique character types and `n_i` is the number of characters of type i in the input. But since `sum_i n_i` is the length of the input, this reduces to `(1/2) * (L + sum_i n_i^2)`

**Code breakdown:**

```
o ½ (§ + L (o Σ (´ (× =)))        --With parentheses and two implicit compositions
                   (× =)          --1 or 0 for each equality check between elements of its first and second arguments
                (´ (× =))         --argdup, 1 or 0 for each equality check between elements of its only argument
           (o Σ (´ (× =))         --# of equalities between pairs (this will give sum_i n_i^2)
         L                        --length
    (§ + L (o Σ (´ (× =)))        --length + sum_i n_i^2
o ½ (§ + L (o Σ (´ (× =)))        --1/2 * (length + sum_i n_i^2)
```

Comment: You can do `Ṡṁ#` instead of `(Σ´×=` for a score of 7.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2. Score:<s>142</s> 115

```
def     f(a):
        x=0
        for y in set(a):z=a.count(y);x+=.5*z*-~z
        print x
```

EDIT:-27 thanks to @Kevin Cruijssen

Comment: By changing the indentations and the space between `def f(a)` to tabs you lower your score to 126. In addition, you can change `(z+1)` to `-~z` to lower it more to 117. And you can remove the `0` in `0.5` to lower it to 115. [**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1jTNNI1HTiouzwtaAizMtv0ihUiEzT6E4tQQkXGWbqJecX5pXolGpaV2hbatnqlWlpVtXxcVZUJSZV6JQ8R@koxikI1opoCg/vSgxNzczL10hoLSqKie1WEFNwTk/JVXBPT8nTUlHQUkBAkBMuNUxeSC7gSSxlgOVQm1XirXiUlBI0yjW/A8A)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks, Changed!

Comment: [Try it online! link](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1jTNNI1HTiouzwtaAizMtv0ihUiEzT6E4tQQkXGWbqJecX5pXolGpaV2hbatnqlWlpVtXxcVZUJSZV6JQ8T9NQ0lJiWJjgGZo/gcA "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes, score 5

```
ΣṁŀgO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9zihzsbjzak@////z8xKTExOTEJAA)

Different and (so far) shorter strategy to [Natte's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241169/95126) or [Sophia Lechner's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/158410/95126) Husk answers.

```
    O   # sort the input
   g    # and group equal adjacent values;
 ṁ      # now, for each group
  ŀ     # make a range 1..length of the group
 ṁ      # and flatten all the ranges into one list;
Σ       # then output the sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), score <s>89</s> 85

```python
lambda	y:sum(y[:x+1].count(v)for	x,v in enumerate(y))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklkbPSqrg0V6My2qpC2zBWLzm/NK9Eo0wzLb@Is0KnTCEzTyE1rzQ3tSixJFWjUlPzf0FRJlBBmoYSWdqVgCYAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, score 83

```python
lambda z:sum((2*z.count(x)+1)**2/8for x in set(z))
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHKqrg0V0PDSKtKLzm/NK9Eo0JT21BTS8tI3yItv0ihQiEzT6E4tUSjSlPzf7FtDJc66frUuQqKMvNKFNI0ijX/AwA)

`1/8 (1 + 2 n)^2 -1/8` is the same as `n (n+1) / 2`. Floor division removes the need to subtract `1/8`.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), score 23

```
$-:@+[:+/,/@(=/~)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P83WSkXXykE72kpbX0ffQcNWv07zf2pyRr5CmoI6how6F0wqMSkxMTkxCSEQUJSfXpSYm5uZl64QUFpVlZNarKCm4Jyfkqrgnp@ThlCIYClAALKhySmpaelIAo7q/wE)

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, score 96

```
#(apply +(for[[k j](frequencies %)](*(inc j)j 0.5)))
```

Five spaces and pairs of brackets...

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), score 12

```
;╗╔⌠╜cRΣ⌡MΣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/9/60dTpj6ZOedSz4NHUOclB5xY/6lnoe27x//9KOGSUAA)

Explanation:

```
;╗╔⌠╜cRΣ⌡MΣ  (implicit input: S)
;╗           save a copy of S in register 0
  ╔          uniquify S (call it A)
   ⌠╜cRΣ⌡M   for each unique character in A:
    ╜c         count the number of occurrences in S
      R        range(1, count+1)
       Σ       sum
          Σ  sum
```

Repeating the `Σ` is two points less than using an alternative formulation with no repeated characters (`` i`+Y ``).

Answer (score 1):

### F#, score:<s>1264</s>1110

-154 points, thanks to @Laikoni

```
let x(y:bool)=System.Convert.ToInt32(y)
let rec p(k:string)q=
 let j=k.Length
 if(j=1)then(x(k.[0]=q))else p k.[0..(j-2)] q+x(k.[j-1]=q)
let rec d(a:string)=
 let z=a.Length
 if(z<2)then z else d a.[0..(z-2)]+p a (a.[z-1])
```

You need to call the d function. In a more readable form:

```
let x (y:bool)=
    System.Convert.ToInt32(y)
let rec e (c:string) b=
    let j=c.Length
    if(j=1)then
        (x(c.[0]=b))
    else 
        e c.[0..(j-2)] b+x (c.[j-1]=b)
let rec d (a:string)=
    let h=a.Length
    if(h<2)then 
        h 
    else
        d a.[0..(h-2)]+e a (a.[h-1])
```

#### Explanation

It is a recursive algorithm, the base case is, if the length of the string is less than 2 (0 or 1), the score will be the length of the string. This is because, if the length is 0 (empty string), we have no characters, so the score is 0, and if the length is 1, that means, that the string consists of only 1 character, so the score is 1.

Otherwise it trims the last character of the string, and to the score of the truncated string adds the count of the last character in the untruncated string.

The counting algorithm is also recursive. Its base case is, when the length of the string is one, then the count is 1, if the string matches with the character, and 0 otherwise. This can also be done, if we convert the bool to an int, and this results in a lower score.

Otherwise it trims the last character of the string, calculates the count of that string, and if the last character matches the character, we are calculating the count of, adds one to the count. This is again, better, if we convert that boolean to an int.

Comment: I think you can remove some white space, e.g. around the parentheses in `let rec e (c:string) b=`. Also using some character as variable which does not appear in keywords will improve your score, e.g. `y` instead of `e`.

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 39 bytes, Score 54

```
BEGIN{RS="(.)"}{M+=++s[RT]}END{print M}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd0686KNhWSUNPU6m22lfbVlu7ODooJLbW1c@luqAoM69EwbeWaIUA)

Comment: Changing `S` to some unused character reduces the score by two.

Answer (score 1):

**FIREBIRD, score 3577**

Version to calculte the score:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(C),0)FROM(WITH RECURSIVE T AS(SELECT 1 AS I,SUBSTRING(CAST(:V AS BLOB)FROM 1 FOR 1)AS S FROM RDB$DATABASE UNION ALL SELECT I+1,SUBSTRING(CAST(:V AS BLOB)FROM I+1 FOR 1)FROM T WHERE I < CHAR_LENGTH(CAST(:V AS BLOB)))SELECT T.*,(SELECT COUNT(T2.I) FROM T T2 WHERE T2.S=T.S AND T2.I<=T.I)AS C FROM T WHERE CAST(:V AS BLOB) <> '')
```

Below is the idented version of the code, in case anyone want to now. I'm sorry for any mistakes, first time here actually posting!

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(C), 0)
FROM (
  WITH RECURSIVE T AS (
    SELECT 1 AS I, SUBSTRING(CAST(:V AS BLOB) FROM 1 FOR 1) AS S
    FROM RDB$DATABASE

    UNION ALL

    SELECT I+1, SUBSTRING(CAST(:V AS BLOB) FROM I+1 FOR 1)
    FROM T
    WHERE I < CHAR_LENGTH(CAST(:V AS BLOB))
  )
  SELECT T.*, (SELECT COUNT(T2.I) FROM T T2 WHERE T2.S = T.S AND T2.I <= T.I) AS C
  FROM T
  WHERE CAST(:V AS BLOB) <> ''
)
```

---

**Explanation**

I start my select in a system table `SELECT 1 AS I, SUBSTRING(CAST(:V AS BLOB) FROM 1 FOR 1) AS S FROM RDB$DATABASE`, which always has only one row. Using that only one row, I return 1 as a column **I**, and the character that exists in the input in the I value.

Let's say I've passed 'abaacab' as input:

```
╔═══╦═══╗
║ I ║ S ║
╠═══╬═══╣
║ 1 ║ a ║
╚═══╩═══╝
```

In the UNION ALL part, I start to increment the index from the first select, until it reaches the end of the input. So, in the example I would get this:

```
╔═══╦═══╗
║ I ║ S ║
╠═══╬═══╣
║ 1 ║ a ║
║ 2 ║ b ║
║ 3 ║ a ║
║ 4 ║ a ║
║ 5 ║ c ║
║ 6 ║ a ║
║ 7 ║ b ║
╚═══╩═══╝
```

After that, I also select the count of ocurrences from the value on **S**, that has already appeared in indexes below the **I**. So, in a column **C** I now have the 'cost' of that character, which I only need to SUM after to get the value.

```
╔═══╦═══╦═══╗
║ I ║ S ║ C ║
╠═══╬═══╬═══╣
║ 1 ║ a ║ 1 ║
║ 2 ║ b ║ 1 ║
║ 3 ║ a ║ 2 ║
║ 4 ║ a ║ 3 ║
║ 5 ║ c ║ 1 ║
║ 6 ║ a ║ 4 ║
║ 7 ║ b ║ 2 ║
╚═══╩═══╩═══╝
```

I used BLOB as the type from the input, to not get limited by size.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: @Laikoni Thanks! I forgot to add a short explanation, my bad. I will do it later, in case anyone is interested.

Comment: I'm always interested in explanations. :) Have you checked for each space wether it can be removed or not? Some of them look unnecessary, e.g. `(SUM(C), 0)` or `AS (SELECT`, thought I don't know firebird.

Comment: Thanks @Laikoni, with your advice I saved some points. I've just add my explanation. If its too bad just let me know so I can try to make a better one.

Answer (score 1):

### [K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_(programming_language))/[Kona](https://github.com/kevinlawler/kona), score 19

```
+/,/1+!:'(#:)'=
```

Works as:

```
              = (implicitly take arg as input), group -> make dictionary of characters to their occurring indices
         (#:)'= count each of these 
    1+!:'(#:)'= get a list from 0->n-1 for each of these counts, add one to each 
+/,/1+!:'(#:)'= finally, reduce to single list, sum reduce this list
```

Example:

```
k)+/,/1+!:'(#:)'="+/,/1+!:'(#:)'="
19
k)+/,/1+!:'(#:)'="abaacab"
14
```

Legible q equivalent:

```
(sum/)raze 1+til count each group
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), score 7

```
cemSss
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=cemSss&input=%5B%22c%22%2C%22e%22%2C%22m%22%2C%22S%22%2C%22s%22%2C%22s%22%5D&warnings=1&hex=0)

```
c      -    count_occurrences(input)
 e     -   values(^)
  mS   -  [range(1,i+1) for i in ^]
    ss - sum(sum(i)for i in ^)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10</s> 9 bytes; Score <s>10</s> 9

```
ṢŒrzẆṪRẎS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzkVHJxVVPdzV9nDnqqCHu/qC/2MTBAA)

This is the first time I use Jelly, and I didn't want to check other people's answers because I wanted to try it myself. I probably reinvented the wheel a couple times there. Suggestions and feedback are greatly appreciated.

EDIT: -1 byte for removing `ɠ` and taking the input as an argument.

Explanation:

```
ṢŒrzẆṪRẎS           #Main Link; input abaacab
Ṣ                   #sorts input; aaaabbc
 Œr                 #run-length encode, or the number of times a character appears; a4b2c1
   z                #zip; ['abc', [4, 2, 1]]
    Ẇ               #takes every contiguous sublists
     Ṫ              #Pops the last element; [4, 2, 1]
      R             #Takes the range of every element; [[1,2,3,4],[1,2],1]
       Ẏ            #Collapses every element into a single array; [1,2,3,4,1,2,1]
        S           #Sum and implicitly print; 14.
```

(no idea why, but the code doesn't work without `Ẇ`,
 although it gives the exact same output as `z`)

Comment: [8 bytes, score of 8](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzkVHJxVFPdy5Ksgt@P///0ooAkoA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), score 12 (+2 for `-x`) = 14

```
¬n ó¥ ËÊõÃc
```

### Explanation

```
¬n ó¥ ËÊõÃc                                             "abaacab"
¬            // Split the input into an array of chars  ["a","b","a","a","c","a","b"]
 n           // Sort                                    ["a","a","a","a","b","b","c"]
   ó¥        // Partition matching items                [["a","a","a","a"],["b","b"],["c"]]
      Ë      // map; For each array:
       Ê     //   Get the length x                      [4,2,1]
        õ    //   Create a range [1...x]                [[1,2,3,4],[1,2],[1]]
         Ã   // }
          c  // Flatten                                 [1,2,3,4,1,2,1]
-x           // Sum                                     14
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AT0Awv9qYXB0///CrG4gw7PCpSDDi8OKw7XDg2P//yJQcm9ncmFtbWluZyBQdXp6bGVzICYgQ29kZSBHb2xmIi14)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), score 14

```
1#.2!1+#/.~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DZX1jBQNtZX19er@a3KlJmfkK6QppJalFlUqqCcmJSYmJyapK1grqAcU5acXJebmZualKwSUVlXlpBYrqCk456ekKrjn56SB1YAJBQgAsxOTklNS09IhbEd1mPHqSJaq/wcA)

Outgolfed by the other J solution, but figured I'd post this anyways since it uses a slightly different method.

Answer (score 1):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/attache), score 36

```
Sum@Map&:(Count#Last)@Prefixes
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP3vkpqWmZcarZKm8z@4NNfBN7FAzUrDOb80r0TZJ7G4RNMhoAiooiK1@H8sV0BRZl5JdFq0En6VSrGx/wE)

### Explanation

```
Sum@Map&:(Count#Last)@Prefixes
```

This is a composition of 3 functions:

- `Prefixes` - this simply obtains the prefixes of the input
- `Map&:(Count#Last)` - This is a mapped fork. This is equivalent to `arr.map { e -> e.count(e.last) }` So, for each character, this counts the occurrences of that character so far.
- `Sum` - this sums all of these numbers.

Answer (score 1):

## MS-SQL, score 308

I'm using a completely different technique from [my other answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127312/70172), with additional restrictions, so I'm submitting them separately:

```sql
SelEcT SUm(k)FROM(SELECT k=couNt(*)*(CoUNT(*)+1)/2froM spt_values,z WHERE type='P'AND number<len(q)GROUP BY sUBstring(q,number+1,1))L
```

Caveats: this must be run from the `master` database of a MS-SQL server set to a case-sensitive collation (mine is set to SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN2).

Input is via varchar field *q* in pre-existing table *z*, [per our IO rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341). Formatted:

```sql
SelEcT SUm(k)
FROM
    (SELECT k=couNt(*)*(CoUNT(*)+1)/2
     froM spt_values,z 
     WHERE type='P'
     AND number<len(q)
     GROUP BY sUBstring(q,number+1,1)
    )L
```

The trick here is to use a "[number table](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/129211/sql-select-number-ranges)"  to join with the input table, which allows me to separate each character into its own row, then group by matching characters, count them up, calculate the score of each, and sum them all together. All the rest is minimizing score by playing with character case, since SQL keywords are not case sensitive.

MS-SQL has a system table in the `master` database called `spt_values` with a lot of junk in it, but I restrict it to `type='P'`, I get a nice number table with 0 through 2047.

Answer (score 1):

## [K4](http://kx.com/download/), score 15

**Solution:**

```
+/,/{1+!#x}'=
```

**Example:**

```
q)k)+/,/{1+!#x}'="Programming Puzzles & Code Golf"
47
```

**Explanation:**

```
+/,/{1+!#x}'= / the solution
            = / group
    {     }'  / apply lambda to each (')
         x    / implicit lambda input
        #     / count length
       !      / range 0..n
     1+       / add one
  ,/          / flatten list
+/            / sum up
```

**Notes:**

In **Q** this could be written as:

```
q)sum raze { 1 + til count x } each group "Programming Puzzles & Code Golf"
47
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <s>112</s> <s>95</s> 58 points

```js
A=>A.map(C=>N+=A[C]=-~A[C],N=0)|N
```

- 7 points saved thanks to ETHProductions

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxNC4JAGITP7a/YUyjqamIkxAoi0U28i7Cvq2uGX6zmQaK/bookzWWYYZ55wgg9l2U3GKM7Czr71PNJDZ0SUC/UqB8HCTU@q@khtdR3OA80RgxSAA4p0w@LTBOfHMQi2RYS6rpsChy9pqnKe3zEQZvl@N5WYtkuQ@eC2EatCVuI4U37le2u9zzLRbF3eKHA/@NsJDTGfvHsouQ6ENHKG/CH0lOvk2UzKEKJCSF9oqrq/AU)

Answer (score 1):

## [Standard ML](http://www.mlton.org/), 66 bytes, score 113

```ml
fun$(a::z)=1+length(List.filter(fn y=>y=a)z)+	$z|
$_=0;$o explode;
```

This code defines an anonymous function which is bound to the implicit result identifier `it`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZBBSwMxEIXP7q8YwiJJi6WVgtIQQXoQwUPB66LMtsm6kE3KZgpt8L@vaVNY8ebc5nvvzcALnb3rLHk3DObgSo6rVRRqMbXaNfTF39pAM9Na0j03Dk7q6aRQRDG9KeN3UX6quSw96OPe@p2W5xNAOhAEULDvW0f81dGM/DulpeFtUgR8AKscE7IoLl6GNeIWayaBT2CxhIm4CpveNz12XYrC5hCj1QFuYZ1ewYu3JgeWD2Mgk/kIIE/m94@jgPV2p02ThV8X8PnqHdG/eqkoFVO5v80wOfwA)

#### Explanation

The ungolfed code looks like this:

```ml
fun f (a::z) = 1 + length (List.filter (fn y => y=a) z) + f z
  | f  _     = 0
val g = f o explode
```

The function `g` takes a string as input, converts it to a list of characters with `explode`, and passes it on to the function `f` which recurses over the list, with `a` being the current character and `z` being the remaining list. For each `a` the number of occurrences of `a` in `z` is computed by filtering `z` to contain only chars equivalent to `a` and taking the length of the resulting list. The result is incremented by one to account for the current occurrence of `a` and added to result of the recursive call of `f` on `z`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>8</s> [6](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ç╕┌α▒'
```

[Run and debug online!](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=87b8dae0b127&i=abaacab%0A%C3%A7%E2%95%95%E2%94%8C%CE%B1%E2%96%92%27&a=1&m=2)

Saved 2 points by using runs per comment by @recursive.

### Explanation

Uses the unpacked version to explain.

```
o:GF:T+
o          Sort array
 :G        Run lengths
   F       For each run length `n`
    :T     The nth triangular number
      +    Add to accumulator
           Implicit output
```

Comment: run-length is good here.  [6](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=87b8dae0b127&i=abaacab%0A%C3%A7%E2%95%95%E2%94%8C%CE%B1%E2%96%92%27&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 44 bytes, score 78:

```php
While($C=ORD($argn[$p++]))$s-=++$$C;EcHo-$s;
```

Almost [Jörg´s solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127353/55735), but one byte shorter.

---

### PHP, 51 bytes, score 80

```php
ForEach(COUNT_CHARS($argn)As$p)$z-=~$p*$p/2;echo$z;
```

---

Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try them online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4c1a902b7e08ecff0edf97bee9b11db9f0652357)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl6/Rakudo](https://perl6.org/), 45 bytes, score 66

Run with `perl -ne`:

```
say [+] bag(.comb).values.map({($_+1)*$_/2});
```

Uses the essential nature of a Bag (like a set with a count per member).

Step by step:

```
.say;                      # abaacab
say .comb;                 # (a b a a c a b)
say bag(.comb);            # Bag(a(4), b(2), c)
say bag(.comb).values;     # (2 4 1)
say bag(.comb).values.map({($_+1)*$_/2});        # (3 10 1)
say [+] bag(.comb).values.map({($_+1)*$_/2});  #14
```

Also note that each character's score can be calculated from its occurrences as `(n+1)*n/2`.

Edited because I cannot evidently read.

Comment: In this challenge, _the score of your submission is the cost of your code_ which I think is 75.

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), score 33

```
0vAB;n*<
p>i:0(?^:ag1+:}r-@a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/36DM0ck6T8uGq8Au08pAwz7OKjHdUNuqtkjXIRG/LAA)

28 bytes, with 2 occurrences each of `a` and `0`, and 3 occurrences of `:`. `AB` can be replaced by any two characters which don't appear anywhere else in the code.

Works by storing the current character count in the code grid on row 10. The sum is actually a negative sum to start with, and the -1 from reaching the end of STDIN is multiplied with this to turn it back into a positive number.

Answer (score 1):

## jq, score 60

(40 characters code + 3 characters command line option)

```
[./""|group_by(.)[]|range(length+1)]|add
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ jq -R '[./""|group_by(.)[]|range(length+1)]|add' <<< 'Programming Puzzles & Code Golf'
47
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z9aT19JqSa9KL@0ID6pUkNPMzq2pigxLz1VIyc1L70kQ9tQM7YmMSXl///EpMTE5MQkroCi/PSixNzczLx0hYDSqqqc1GIFNQXn/JRUBff8nDQuLgUI4EpMSk5JTUvnSnTk0g1SINaif/kFJZn5ecX/dYMA)

#### jq, score 63

```
[./""|group_by(.)[]|range(length+1)]|add+0
```

In case the result for empty string must be numeric 0. There are a few other solutions that use alternative representation of nothing.

Answer (score 1):

**SHELL** ( **67 bytes**)

**Last Solution :** ( **68 bytes**)

```
 f(){ bc<<<`echo -n "$1"|od -bAn|sed "s/\([^ ]\+\)/s+=++v\1;/g"`s;}
```

Old solutions :

**Old Solution 1** : by creating **function f** (**83 bytes** ) :

```
f(){ bc<<<`echo "$1"|sed "s/./ss+=++&;/g"|sed "s/[A-Z]/\L&_/g"|sed "s/ /bb/g"`ss;}
```

**Old Solution 2** : by creating **alias f** ( **81 bytes** )

```
alias f='bc<<<`cat -|sed "s/./ss+=++&;/g"|sed "s/[A-Z]/\L&_/g"|sed "s/ /bb/g"`ss'
```

**Explanations :**
I used  ( **sed "s/./ss+=++&;/g"** ) to replace any char **a** by  ( **ss+=++a;** ); where ss is the sum to calculate, then concatenate with ss, and calculate all expression by the command **bc** :

```
echo "a" | sed "s/./ss+=++&;/g"
ss+=++a;
```

for a string in input :

```
echo "aab" | sed "s/./ss+=++&;/g"
ss+=++a;ss+=++a;ss+=++b;
```

step by step :

```
ss+=++a;    // a=1  -->  ss=1
ss+=++a;    // a=2  -->  ss=3
ss+=++b;    // b=1  -->  ss=4
```

for lowercase only input, the simpler function need only ( **47 bytes** ) to define :

```
f(){ bc<<<`echo "$1"|sed "s/./ss+=++&;/g"`ss;}
```

to take uppercase in consideration, Without spaces ( **68 bytes**) :

```
f(){ bc<<<`echo "$1"|sed "s/./ss+=++&;/g"|sed "s/[A-Z]/\L&_/g"`ss;}
```

Complete Solution ( **83 bytes**):

```
f(){ bc<<<`echo "$1"|sed "s/./ss+=++&;/g"|sed "s/[A-Z]/\L&_/g"|sed "s/ /bb/g"`ss;}
```

**fuction tests** :

```
f "abaacab"
14

f "abcdefg"
7

f "       "
28

f "Aa"
2
```

using an alias instead the function, we can reduce code size to ( **68 bytes** )

```
alias f='bc<<<`cat -|sed "s/./ss+=++&;/g"|sed "s/[A-Z]/\L&_/g"|sed "s/ /bb/g"`ss'
```

**alias tests** :

```
echo "       " | f
28

echo "Ab" | f
2
```

Comment: *The score of your submission is the cost of your code*, that is 241 for the 84-byte version and 232 for the 81 byte version.

Comment: Since this challenge is not scored by length, you should list the scores instead of byte counts.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), score: 38

```ruby
->z{z.sum{|k|z.count(k)+1}/2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY89D4IwEIb3/oqLgx8R8YtEF02Mgys76VDaUho@SoAmWuG3YxXQzVvuuefeXHKlDh9ddOpWZ/M0bqWzZ5M0xqVK5/U8WSy37XrXdoWuK5jJ3PYZ6gehvsjvBac1Z/2MUIAAgsnfixMH9kfsfIIkJISS0KqtNyi/VKIkWSZzAb42JuUVTOGqGIebSiMb9Q5D1PJmQOjLmt3vNmU8ElaNeXJ57zHCLic0BqagkY5q7O7zjBwhCqRLY1JWeDRqAMRz1r0A)

Answer (score 1):

## R, 349

Here is my R solution bit of tidy

```
s=function(x) {c=0
for (i in unique(strsplit(x,"")[[1]])) {
c=c(c,sum(1:sum(charToRaw(x)==charToRaw(i))))}
sum(c)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! The point of this challenge is to make the score (the output of running your code on your code) as small as possible. This would have quite a large score! I would be more than happy to help you reduce the score.

Comment: Thanks @Giuseppe will work to improve it! Cheers

Comment: This answer still has a lot of unnecessary whitespace and long variable names it. Also, in order to be a valid solution, you'll need to provide the current byte count. (which is currently `174`)

Comment: While in the counting part you use `charToRaw()`, better use it instead `strsplit()` too. [Score 195](https://tio.run/##K/qv8T@tNC@5JDM/T6NCs9rZRteAKy2/SMNTITNPoTQvs7A0VSPURjc5I7EoJD8osRyoSFMTqCpZw1mnuDRXw9AKRIba2noCxblAbGfN2v@aGurUN1Vd8z8A "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @manatwork thanks for your advice but it is not quite clear when you would use strsplit()

Comment: Uhm… Never. Both functions decomposes the string into vectors of unique values per character, so I suggested to work exclusively with raws. BTW, the code I linked has the score of 195. Your currently posted code's score is 456. ☹

Comment: @manatwork just amended thanks working on cut it short now!

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), score 93

```
{it.foldIndexed(0){z,q,v->q+it.take(z+1).count{it==v}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY5LDoIwFEXnrOLFURs@0SkRjEMSZ67gQQtpwFcohSika8eKcQPe6bk5Oa22naKtnggeqIihacYUrsbg63y3RlGTc1gD8Juxg0qPNgX2JRziHAqykG2rskmtO1GQkE8p2JGvSzREc5wPoUcWW8mW8MSTSk9k/TvLZufc9vMq6ifvASNR3BRJxuGSwuFP7WHv7X2jZZ9itus5D9yGJWKF5Rs)

Answer (score 1):

## [Reticular](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/reticular), score 56

```
iSd:A=>ddV@c~dc$:A=+:A`L0EQ6jj+1*37_$O;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otyUwuzUks@v8/MzjFytHWLiUlzCG5LiVZBcjRtnJM8DFwDTTLytI21DI2j1fxt/7/HwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), Score: 34

```perl6
{sum [\+](^∞)[.comb.Bag{*}]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzRasIwFEDf8xWXUJrE1WBFtrFiQcfYiw/CYC@1g7QmpZAYSeyDiu/7in3cfqSGeJ/u4Z5zj9Lp59GcIVGwJOPVDwaq3VNNf/5//1jFW2savhbddXKrbyPhfmj8ydE8m0xzVqAQpiEEnCYK84/v1aZAXpwpr2Z1RJ6qjEDvgWS8ymsGyjrQ/UH6suT@qPsTxTAtAbMYAvlqrZNvQVc0UawYsWiEaEUTrXyB8NbZzglj@kMH2@Fy0dJDCu92L@HTahW9xQvCcZkhDI@JOH9F4V@7l6qLHDSxelzu)

Takes advantage of the unicode operator `∞` to save on characters.

#### Explanation

```perl6
{                          }  # Anonymous code block
              .comb           # Split the input string into characters
                   .Bag{*}    # Get the count of each character
             [            ]   # And inded each into
         (^∞)                 # The infinite list of integers
     [\+]                     # Triangularly summed (0,0+1,0+1+2...)
 sum                          # And return the sum total
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), Score: <s>209</s> <s>196</s> 193

<s>98</s> 96 bytes

*-3 thanx to l4m2*

```cpp
#include<map>
long	F(std::string	S,int I=0){for(auto&C:S){++I;for(char&D:S)I+=C==D;}return I/2;}
```

C++-specific tricks:

- `#include<map>` instead of `#include<string>`
- Returning `long` instead of `int` to use more different characters
- Using `auto` instead of `char` in one of the loops has the same effect
- References (`&`) inside range-for save whitespace

Common tricks:

- Evenly use both tabs and blanks
- Upper case variables to be distinct from keyword characters

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVBNa4NAED1nf8VgiOyipaVHrYFiSPEWyDWXcT/sgu7KukKI@NvtSrGl985l5r03zLwZ3vdPDefLXhvejkK@8cELbY@/RIf9kbTWNLszDVqWDd7pgK6pNh6q4oVNyjqKo7dxmV3ZlCRVvjL8E118CkyVFGVRnPLZST86A9Xzaz4veyGVNhIUvTPow0ivaHQYMjiIm4nSe3oOAssJWdd0qA1lE9mFHqwROdZR0FZ4cbZx2HXBE1zGx6OVA8RQWiHhw7Zqa9syfMcGsebBR/MD37fqz/038/8PiBiZly8)

Comment: [193](https://tio.run/##rVBNa4NAED1nf8VgiOyipaVHrYFiSPEWyDWXcT/sgu7KukKI@NvtSrGl985l5r03zLwZ3vdPDefLXhvejkK@8cELbY@/RIf9kbTWNLszDVqWDd7pgK6pNh6q4oVNyjqKo7dxmV3ZlCRVvjL8E118CkyVFGVRnPLZST86A9Xzaz4veyGVNhIUvTPow0ivaHQYMjiIm4nSe3oOAssJWdd0qA1lE9mFHqwROdZR0FZ4cbZx2HXBE1zGx6OVA8RQWiHhw7Zqa9syfMcGsebBR/MD37fqz/038/8PiBiZly8)

Comment: Your code is  still 196

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <s>150</s> <s>141</s> 133

```
f=(g,i=[])=>g?(i[j=g.charCodeAt()]=(i[j]|0)+1)+f(g.substr(1),i):0
```

Ungolfed:

```
f=(g,i=[])=>                                                       //function declaration, a is list of appearance of characters so far.
            g?                                                     //check if string is empty
              (i[j=g.charCodeAt()]=                                //update appearance list
                                    (i[j]|0)+1)+                   //handle undefined, then increment
                                                f(g.substr(1),i)   //next character
                                                                :0 //base case for the empty string
```

150->141 - -6 for renaming variables to unique characters (thanks to Ørjan Johansen), and -3 for removing implicit `0` in `charCodeAt`.

141->133 - -8 for using actual unique variable names(thanks again to Ørjan Johansen).

Comment: The variable names `s,a,c` give you a higher score than necessary because they're used as characters in `charCodeAt` and `subStr`.

Comment: @Ørjan Johansen Hmm, then let's see if I can do better

Comment: `b` and `d` are still not unique. I think `i` and `j` are the first vacant ones.

Comment: @Ørjan Johansen Oh yeah true

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 36 bytes, score 52

```sh
for	p (${(s..)1})$[j+=++a[#p]]
<<<$j
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@G@nkKZgY6Og7urvpv4/Lb@Is0BBQ6Vao1hPT9OwVlMlOkvbVls7MVq5IDaWy8bGRiXrP1AlV0lRaV5yYkmqgm6xgq6hQhpXVXEG0KDEpMTE5MQkKK80L7Pw8K5UmBwySEpKSk6GSiipaNikaSr9BwA)

One tab, one space, one newline. This will fill up the debug log with "command not found". If that must be avoided, [38 bytes, score 55](https://tio.run/##qyrO@G@nkKZgY6Og7urvpv4/Lb@Is0BBQ6Vao1hPT9OwVtNKQSU6S9tWWzsxWrkgNpbLxsZGJes/UC2XcklRaV5yYkmqgm6xgq6hQhpXVXEG0KzEpMTE5MQkKK80L7Pw8K5UmBwySEpKSk6GSiipaNikaSr9BwA).

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), score: 4 (4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage))

```
Ù¢LO
```

Input as a list of characters.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8MxDi3z8//@PVj88U11H/dAiIOEDxP7qsQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9WGXx4gr2SwqO2SQpK9v8Pzzy0yMf/v87/aKXEpMTE5MQkJR2lgKL89KLE3NzMvHSFgNKqqpzUYgU1Bef8lFQF9/ycNKAKIFKAACArMSk5JTUtHcRyBBIQI5ViAQ).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ù     # Get all unique characters of the (implicit) input-list
 ¢    # For each, count the amount of times it occurs in the (implicit) input-list
  L   # Create a list of each of these counts
      # (which implicitly flattens in the legacy version of 05AB1E)
   O  # Take the sum of all those integers
      # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>150</s> 133 points

(<s>79</s> 75 bytes)

```hs
import Data.List
c=foldr(\x->	\y->y+(x*(x+1)`div`2))0.map length.group.sort
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZAxa8MwEIXn5lccohS7JqbtnkBpIUuGQDtqyEWSZRFJZ6Rz6@TPuw4pHeKpb/y4ew@@FvPReD@OLnSUGN6Rsd66zAu1asjrVMhhub6Tp@X6VBXDYzFUz@Veu6/9S1k@1QE78CZabmubqO/qPJWMAV2EFWhawJQuuchwDwoEHhAVHsQt3yWyCUNw0cKuP5@9yfAAb6QNbMg3s/sZgGvEfFBp09g5f/1FPX9wmpj4bF0GdVlUlDlPlVUFRW7p@/px60fGP0EXQ5LlvxyJcvwB)

- -17 points by removing some parentheses (thanks to @Laikoni)

Comment: You can drop the parenthesis around the `foldr` expression and just write `map length` instead of `(map$length)` for a score of 133.

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), score: <s>11</s> 10

```
$uC¦ₔ┅¦_Σ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/X6XU@dCyR01THk1pPbQs/txiTBEA)

<s>For some reason, `_` is necessary else this spits out garbage answers. But the language is defined by its implementation, so what are ya gonna do.</s> Without the `_`, one of the sublists generated by `┅¦`is `[1 2]` which is converted to `12` by `Σ`.

```
$		| split into characters
 		| 
  u		| get unique
   C¦ₔ		| implicitly copy original input; get counts of uniques into original
      ┅¦	| sequence: 1..count
        _Σ	| flatten and sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 87 score

```javascript
A=([B,...C],Z=0)=>B?C.map(D=>D!=B||Z++)^A(C)-~Z:0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcpBC4IwGMbxe59iecgNdXQOZkyFrp6NgledsnJuTAsS6auvQxDtuf1/PDd4wtRYaeZkMrIVVunxLl7OcYbPWUwpzS9xxfaEpdkxpwoMLlhabFm2rlUUkSvHOUne1WHvjJXjjDkOoAZooA4I2fystLq3oJQce1Q@lmUQE9qhXLcCnfTQeV8v0HeeQd20out94/8ZchZGnBD3AQ)

`C.map(D=>D!=B||Z++)` is either empty, `0`, `true` or something with a `,`, making it never show value to `^`

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `d`, 3 bytes

```
Ċɾ⌊
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJkIiwiIiwixIrJvuKMiiIsIiIsImFiYWFjYWIiXQ==)

```
Ċ   # Counts of each element within itself
 ɾ  # Convert each value to 1...n
  ⌊ # Parse each to integer, zeroes element values
    # (d flag) take the deep sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 8 bytes, Score: 9

```
ssSM/LQ{
```

[Test suite](http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=ssSM%2FLQ%7B&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22abaacab%22%0A%22Programming+Puzzles+%26+Code+Golf%22%0A%22%22%0A%22+++++++%22%0A%22abcdefg%22%0A%22aA%22%0A%22ssSM%2FLQ%7B%22&debug=0)

###### Explanation

```
ssSM/LQ{  | Full code
ssSM/LQ{Q | with implicit variables filled
----------+-------------------------------
     L {Q | Map over deduplicated input:
    /LQ   |  count in input
  SM      | Map: to [1...N]
 s        | Flatten
s         | Sum
```

`ss` can be replaced with `s.n` for an identical score with no repeat bytes, at the cost of being one byte longer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), Score: 6

```
ṁoΣ#¹u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOxvxzi5UP7Sz9//9/YlJiYnJiEgA)

#### Explanation

```
ṁoΣ#¹u   translates to ṁoΣ#⁰u⁰
ṁ    u⁰  map following function on unique input and then sum
 o       composed function
   #⁰    count occurrences in input
  Σ      triangular number
```

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, Score: 206

```
G4 =MID(B3,SEQUENCE(LEN(B3)),1)
C3 =IF(B3<>"",SUM(EXACT(G4#,TRANSPOSE(G4#))/2)+ROWS(G4#)/2,)
```

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJniHXkIZ6_u41vbOv?e=Nd85RM)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA Immediate Window, Score <s>159</s> 141

*-18 byte thank to @TaylorRaine*

```
FOR I=1TO[len(b3)]:for J=1to i:Y=Y-(MID([B3],i,1)=mid([B3],j,1)):NEXT:next:?y
```

The mixed case reduces the score by 30.

Comment: Answers are not required to be self resetting, so you can drop the `y=0:`, and just note that y needs to be cleared before being run - you can also get rid of one of the spaces by using `TO[len(b3)]:`

Comment: Something that I hadn't noticed earlier is that you can replace `NEXT:next` with `NEXT j,i` to drop a single character - not sure if that will help to lower the score, but it is an option

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2, score 108

```
lambda S:sum(S.count(Q)*(S.count(Q)+1)/2for Q in set(S))
```

Still golfing :)

Comment: I think you missed the scoring system.

Comment: @LeakyNun Oh shoot you're right –– and that was fast

Comment: `S.count(Q)*(S.count(Q)+1)/2for Q in set(S)` should be the same as `(S.count(Q)+1)/2for Q in S`

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (Firefox 30+), score 68

```
S=>[for(C of(T=0,S))T+=S.split(C).length]&&T/2
```

This uses [array comprehensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Array_comprehensions) which were originally planned for ES7, but were dropped late in the process. Firefox had implemented them anyway.

Comment: I thought those were ES6...?

Comment: @CalculatorFeline No, they didn't make it in favour of `map`/`filter` with arrow functios

Comment: *planned for ES6

Answer (score 0):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), score: 128

```
dim x(126)[_l;||i=asc(_sA,a,1|)┘x(i)=x(i)+1][126|[x(b)|p=p+c}?p
```

Nice round score of 128.

### Explanation

```
dim x(126)      Create an array of 126 elements (one for each ASCII element)
[_l;||          Read cmd line input, loop over its length
i=asc(_sA,a,1|) Read the next char's ascii value
┘               (Syntactic linebreak)
x(i)=x(i)+1     Raise the count of this ASCII char by 1
]               NEXT
[126|           Loop over the ASCII array again
[x(b)|          Read the count and start a loop that runs from 1 to that count
p=p+c           Add to running total p the loop counter
}               Close both loops
?p              PRINT p
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), score <s>63</s> 60

Uses the `-n` flag which ends up adding 2 points due to the presence of another `n` within the code.

-3 points from Alexis Anderson.

```ruby
i=x=0
gsub(/./){x+=$_[0,i+=1].count$&};p x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyvrFgEpBR08/5n2lbYGnClF5cmaejr6WtWV2jbqsRHG@hkatsaxuol55fmlaio1VoXKFT8/5@YlJiYnJjEFVCUn16UmJubmZeuEFBaVZWTWqygpuCcn5Kq4J6fk8bFpQABXIlJySmpaelciY5ceWCLHIixCAA)

Comment: why not use a different variable than `s` since `s` is in `gsub`. It would save you 3 points, I believe.

Comment: @AlexisAndersen wow I can't believe I missed that

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 3, 153 bytes, score = 637

```
var u:(String)->Int={var d = Dictionary<Character,Int>()
for c in $0.characters{d[c] = (d[c] ?? 0) + 1}
return d.values.reduce(0,{$0 + $1 * ($1 + 1) / 2})}
```

### Legible version plus explanation

```
func unique(_ string: String) -> Int {
    var dict = Dictionary<Character, Int>()
    for char in string.characters { dict[char] = (dict[char] ?? 0) + 1 }
    return dict.values.reduce(0, { $0 + $1 * ($1 + 1) / 2 })
}
```

My solution takes the string, iterates over the characters and tracks each unique character in a dictionary, counting the occurrences per character. Once that's done, it reduces the dictionary's values using the triangle number formula ( n(n+1) / 2 ) and returns the result.

### Comments

Swift obviously isn't the best language for golfing, but it was fun to see where I could save bytes despite its rigid syntax. This is my first Swift submission - be gentle!

Answer (score 0):

## ><> (Fish), score 133

```
!<01-0&i:2(:?&:?n?;&1+&:}}:3(00@@?.~~:{=&+&{$}8e+0.>.!06}~{
```

This code reads the input per character, adds a point and loops through all the read characters, adding an extra point for every equal character.

[You can try it out here](https://fishlanguage.com/playground/yia9mvD4zNTXfwLpv)

## Explanation

```
!<01-0&         // Initialize (put -1 on the stack and 0 in the register)
i:2(:?$:?n?;    // Read the next input. If it's -1, print the register and end the program.
&1+&            // Add one to the register
:}}:            // Duplicate both the input and the check value
3(00@@?.~~      // If the check value is -1, jump the instruction pointer to 0,0 (line 0)
:{=&+&          // Compare the input to the check value and add the result to the register
{$}8e+0.        // Move the checked value to the bottom of the stack and jump to 22,0 (line 4)
>.!06}~{        // Clean up the stack and jump to 0,6 (line 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), score 18

```
q_,{)W$<}%.e=0+:+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/vzBep1ozXMWmVlUv1dZA20r7//@Aovz0osTc3My8dIWA0qqqnNRiBTUF5/yUVAX3/Jw0AA)

#### Explanation

```
q                  e# Read the input.
 _,                e# Copy it, get its length.
   {               e# Map over the range from 0 .. length-1:
    )              e#  Increment the current number.
     W$            e#  Push the input.
       <           e#  Get the first <current number> characters of it.
        }%         e# (end map)
          .e=      e# Count the occurrences of each character in the corresponding slice.
             0+    e# Append a 0 to the result (because you can't reduce and empty list).
               :+  e# Reduce by addition (sum).
```

Comment: You can replace `0+:+` with `1b` (convert from base 1, which handles empty list and doesn't have the duplicated character), which gets you a score of 15.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 49 bytes, score 88

```
b={};s=0;for(j in a=prompt())s+=b[a[j]]=-~b[a[j]]
```

Comment: The score of each submission is not the byte count, but the **cost** of the submission, that is the program run on its own source code. This means your score is 88 instead of 49.

Answer (score 0):

## Factor, 2435

(o god my score)

`"" over [ 2dup swap in? [ drop ] [ suffix ] if ] each { } swap swapd [ dupd 0 swap swapd swap [ over = swap [ [ 1 + ] [ ] if ] dip ] each drop swap [ suffix ] dip ] each drop [ dup 1 + * 2 / ] map sum`
(wrong formatting on purpose for multi-line span)

Wow, Factor is hard. Or I'm just bad. Probably a little bit of both.

Comment: Could you tell me what needs to be added in order to test this code on [Try it online](https://tio.run/##XY3BDsIgEER/ZcKxPdj2bvwQ4gGhRA4VQqWaNH47LktrGi@7M7uTN1bpp485CwG/jBESg0kB80sFuMeFvIk@4EpiTta6N0lnaYxK37HiU6NlmBJOtLrjjaWs8PPuJHq0DN1oxoWdyX1b7lf5/@cmhjQYcKLfVBrTlLO66S8 "Factor – Try It Online")?

Comment: @Laikoni add the string to the beginning of the code. So, for `abaacab`, the code will read `"abaacab" "" over [ 2dup `...

Comment: @Laikoni Come to think of it, you'd have to add `USING: kernel sequences sets math ;` to the beginning, too, (they're libraries). Also, it's working on my local machine but not on TIO, and IDK why. Never used Factor on TIO.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

```
ĐỤ⇹ɔ△Ʃ
```

Explanation:

```
              Implicit input
Đ             Duplicate top of stack
 Ụ            Get unique characters
  ⇹           Swap top two items on stack
   ɔ          Count number of times each unique character occurs in the input
    △         Calculates the total score for each character
     Ʃ        Sum count
              Implicit output
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yISHu5c8at95csqjaZuPrcQQAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `grouping.extras math.unicode`, score: 104

```
[ head-clump
[ dup
last '[
_ =
] count
] map
Σ ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lcu9DcIwEAbQ/qb4RENFBgBRIxoaRBVF6ORcfoRjm/NZIvOwDysZVqB61RvYWdR6u54vpz1GjSXNYWzkZcoZD9EgHlmeRYKTjEFXLGxTU8LsYi9IKmZr0jkYDkSbFpNwv3O@LIla9CWR52zYtnTHkTq4WIL9XDjR541uU/8u1bH3aOoX)

The whitespace is a killer. In order to lessen its impact, I alternate between spaces and newlines. Tabs aren't allowed in TIO's build of Factor or I would have used them too.