# SQL select number ranges

Tags: code-golf, tips, syntax, sql

I found it quite hard to achieve a range of numbers as rows in `MySQL`.

For example the range 1-5 is achieved by:

```
SELECT 1 
UNION
SELECT 2
UNION
SELECT 3
UNION
SELECT 4
UNION
SELECT 5
```

will result in:

> ```
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5
> ```

for 0-99 I can cross join two 0-9 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE nums as
SELECT 0 as num
UNION
SELECT 1 
UNION
SELECT 2
UNION
SELECT 3
UNION
SELECT 4
UNION
SELECT 5
UNION
SELECT 6 
UNION
SELECT 7
UNION
SELECT 8
UNION
SELECT 9
;

Select n.num*10+nums.num v 
From nums n cross join nums
```

I'm tired of writing all these `UNION`s and looking for a way to shrink the code.

Any ideas how to **golf it** (for example 0-1,000,000 range) in MySQL or any SQL syntax ?

**Extra points** are given for:

- single statement
- no procedures
- no variables
- no DDL statements
- only DQL statements

Comment: Not sure if this belongs in meta, or in dba.stackexchange.com or maybe in the [tips for Golfing in SQL thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/32796/tips-for-golfing-in-t-sql).

Comment: To close voters: This is an on-topic challenge; questions that aren't challenges that are related to golfing code are considered on-topic tips questions.

Comment: I kinda like [this answer from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21286493/2004841). Hackish at best, but you asked for a golfing solution after all.

Comment: @Arnauld that's amazing!

Comment: [Large list of methods for creating a number table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393951/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-and-populate-a-numbers-table), although they're evaluated by speed, not by golfing ability.

Comment: If “any SQL” includes PostgreSQL, see [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SERIES). We have a couple of [usage examples](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=generate_series) here.

Comment: @manatwork Looks useful, I'd say add it as an answer. Mine are already platform specific.

Comment: See http://www.itprotoday.com/microsoft-sql-server/virtual-auxiliary-table-numbers (for SQL Server 2005 or later).

Answer (score 9):

For SQL dialects that support [recursive CTEs](https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html) like sqlite, you can do something like the following:

```
WITH RECURSIVE f(x) AS
(
  SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT x + 1 FROM f LIMIT 1000000
)
SELECT x
FROM f;
```

This doesn't depend on any existing table and you can change the LIMIT clause as desired. I originally saw a variant of this on StackOverflow.

Comment: Excellent. Here's a golfed version that works in MS SQL: `WITH t AS(SELECT 1n UNION ALL SELECT n+1FROM t WHERE n<36)SELECT n FROM t`  For different end points, just change the `1` and `36` to whatever you want.

Comment: Oops, if you want more than 100 rows in MS SQL, you might need to add `option (maxrecursion 0)` to the end of my above statement , otherwise it errors out for recursion over 100. (Either set `maxrecursion` to a specific value, or to 0 to allow infinite).

Answer (score 6):

Similar to [@BradC's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/129221/61613).

I used MS SQL, which has a table in `[master]` with a number range of -1 through 2048. You can use the `BETWEEN` operator to create your range.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT(number)
FROM master..[spt_values] 
WHERE number BETWEEN 1 AND 5
```

If you want to golf this, you can do:

```sql
SELECT TOP 5 ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY number)FROM master..spt_values
```

Comment: For golfing you save 2 bytes with `WHERE number>0AND number<21`

Comment: Why do you use distinct? Seems redundant.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Because there are duplicate numbers in that table.

Comment: Yep you either need to use DISTINCT or use WHERE type='P'. Distinct is slightly shorter.

Comment: @BradC, or `SELECT DISTINCT(number+2)... WHERE number<19`

Answer (score 5):

#### PostgreSQL, 35 bytes

PostgreSQL has this easy:

```
SELECT * FROM generate_series(1,5)
```

If you need it named:

```
SELECT num FROM generate_series(1,5)AS a(num)
```

You can also do this with timestamps. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-srf.html

Comment: I guess I'm moving to postgres

Answer (score 4):

Great option [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186756/generating-a-range-of-numbers-in-mysql/21286493#21286493) (found by @Arnauld):

```
SELECT id%1000001 as num
FROM <any_large_table>
GROUP BY num
```

For me - it's pretty much solves the challenge.

Comment: This seems to be relying on an existing table already having an `id` field populated through very large values. So pretty database specific, and you could miss a row if, say, someone deleted product ID = 4021.

Comment: Yep, but it really good for relatively small ranges (1-7 for days, 1-12 for months etc...)

Answer (score 4):

## PostgreSQL specific

[`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SERIES) generates a set, so you can user it not only in `from` clause, but anywhere where a set may occur:

```
psql=# select generate_series(10, 20, 3);
 generate_series 
-----------------
              10
              13
              16
              19
(4 rows)
```

You can also do operations directly on the set:

```
psql=# select 2000 + generate_series(10, 20, 3) * 2;
 ?column? 
----------
     2020
     2026
     2032
     2038
(4 rows)
```

If multiple sets have the same length, you can traverse them in parallel:

```
psql=# select generate_series(1, 3), generate_series(4, 6);
 generate_series | generate_series 
-----------------+-----------------
               1 |               4
               2 |               5
               3 |               6
(3 rows)
```

For sets with different lengths a Cartesian product is generated:

```
psql=# select generate_series(1, 3), generate_series(4, 5);
 generate_series | generate_series 
-----------------+-----------------
               1 |               4
               2 |               5
               3 |               4
               1 |               5
               2 |               4
               3 |               5
(6 rows)
```

But if you use them in `from` clause, you get Cartesian product for same length sets too:

```
psql=# select * from generate_series(1, 2), generate_series(3, 4) second;
 generate_series | second 
-----------------+--------
               1 |      3
               1 |      4
               2 |      3
               2 |      4
(4 rows)
```

It can also generate set of timestamps. For example you born on 2000-06-30 and want to know in which years you celebrated your birthday in a weekend:

```
psql=# select to_char(generate_series, 'YYYY - Day') from generate_series('2000-06-30', current_date, interval '1 year') where to_char(generate_series, 'D') in ('1', '7');
     to_char      
------------------
 2001 - Saturday 
 2002 - Sunday   
 2007 - Saturday 
 2012 - Saturday 
 2013 - Sunday   
(5 rows)
```

Answer (score 3):

(These work in MS-SQL, not sure if they works for mySQL or other platforms.)

For smaller sets (ordered or non-ordered), use the `VALUES` constructor:

```sql
--Generates 0-9
SELECT a 
FROM(VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9))x(a)
```

(This works for anything, although strings can get pretty long with all the repeated single quotes.)

Then you can cross-multiply using a named CTE (common table expression) so you don't have to repeat it:

```sql
--Generates 0-999
WITH x AS(SELECT a FROM(VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9))x(a))
SELECT 100*x.a+10*y.a+z.a 
FROM x,x y,x z
ORDER BY 1
```

There are tons of other techniques out there, look for "SQL generating a number table", although most aren't optimized for golfing.

Comment: Would this work with a `limit Y` to make arbitrary ranges?

Comment: @Rod In MS-SQL you'd have to use `SELECT TOP 250 ...`

Comment: Oh, I didn't saw the MSSQL header =X

Comment: doesn't work on MySQL, but still is useful :)

Answer (score 3):

MS SQL has an undocumented system table in the `master` database called `spt_values`. Among other things, it contains a range of numbers from 0 to 2047:

```sql
--returns 0 to 2,047
SELECT number n 
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE TYPE='P'
```

Useful as a numbers table just by itself, but in a CTE you can get some big numbers pretty quickly:

```sql
--returns 0 to 4,194,304
WITH x AS(SELECT number n FROM master..spt_values WHERE TYPE='P')
SELECT 2048*x.a+*y.a
FROM x,x y
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 2):

One more option, this one specific to MS SQL 2016 and above:

```sql
SELECT value v
FROM STRING_SPLIT('1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16', ',')
```

I'll likely find this more handy for lists of strings, but I can see ways it will be useful with numbers as well.

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL, 98 bytes

```
WITH H AS(SELECT 0i UNION ALL SELECT i+1FROM H WHERE i<99)SELECT H.i+1e4*A.i+B.i*1e2FROM H,H A,H B
```

- ✓ single statement
- ✓ no procedures
- ✓ no variables
- ✓ no DDL statements
- ✓ only DQL statements

Comment: This is a nice tidy T-SQL version of [langelgjm's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/129232/70172). The exponents are a neat trick, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Another for SQL Server...

```
WITH 
    cte_n1 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n (n)),   -- 10
    cte_n2 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte_n1 a CROSS JOIN cte_n1 b),                             -- 100
    cte_Tally (n) AS (
        SELECT TOP (<how many ROWS do you want?>)
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
        FROM
            cte_n2 a CROSS JOIN cte_n2 b                                                    -- 10,000
        )
SELECT 
    t.n
FROM
    cte_Tally t;
```