# Enumerate each series of identical numbers in-place

Tags: code-golf, number, integer, sorting, substitution

Given a list of strictly positive integers, go through each distinct number and replace all occurrences of it with successive indices (zero or one based) of a new series.

### Examples

`[]` → `[]`/`[]`

`[42]` → `[0]`/`[1]`

`[7,7,7]` → `[0,1,2]`/`[1,2,3]`

`[10,20,30]` → `[0,0,0]`/`[1,1,1]`

`[5,12,10,12,12,10]` → `[0,0,0,1,2,1]`/`[1,1,1,2,3,2]`

`[2,7,1,8,2,8,1,8,2,8]` → `[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3]`/`[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4]`

`[3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5,3,5,9]` → `[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,1]`/`[1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,2]`

Comment: So basically the number of times it has appeared the sequence so far?

Comment: @JoKing Yes, that's another way to state it, but "so far" implies zero-based, and "until and including this" implies one-based. I wanted to keep the choice.

Answer (score 23):

## JavaScript (ES6), 26 bytes

1-indexed.

```javascript
a=>a.map(o=x=>o[x]=-~o[x])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc7NDoIwDADgu0/BEZIC@wHFw3gRwmFBMBpkRIzh5KvPFoMSB2u2Llm/dlf91EN1v/SPsDOn2jbKapXr6KZ736hR5aYYSxW@KAW2Mt1g2jpqzdlv/KIMAm9jxbFXlLu/@kRsCqrnDjgAxrqZAAiQDuIMBAPJVtwHYTgoBS4AJZ10WeAvomkgHCrwkxwyfM3mPOsfJSymBhISp4XE9wR3Ckes2WOWdKc2y@nLVvQT@wY)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>                // a[] = input array
  a.map(o =         // assign the callback function of map() to the variable o, so that
                    // we have an object that can be used to store the counters
    x =>            // for each value x in a[]:
      o[x] = -~o[x] //   increment o[x] and yield the result
                    //   the '-~' syntax allows to go from undefined to 1
  )                 // end of map()
```

Comment: I have no idea how that works, but it sure looks elegant.

Comment: I've not seen `-~` before - that is an absolute gem.

Comment: Alternatively, it's possible to use `a` to store the values, but it's required to `-`/`~` the index so no byte is saved.

Comment: @DaveMongoose [Tips for golfing in JavaScript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/22017/69850)

Comment: Too bad this isn't C++, otherwise something like `a=>a.map(x=>++(a[-x]|=0))` would save a byte.

Comment: @DaveMongoose `-~` is actually a commonly used alternative to `+1` (since it has different precedence) in many languages

Comment: @ASCII-only Thanks for the info. I also like how the bitwise negation bulldozes through `undefined`

Answer (score 10):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 27 bytes

```r
function(x)ave(x,x,FUN=seq)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYvNCgIxDITvPoXHBEZo011/QK8evfkAUlrYgxV3Xenb1xQiYTJfJsnc8va8a3kt8TO9ClV@fBNVVFzvt8uS3twylfWZ5imSY95kijSIwQFaxt5BHML/ZoQXaNZ7B4tFPzyOEJW5bYLOg2rESdO9eujM3H4)

**Explanation :**

`ave(x,x,FUN=seq)` splits vector `x` into sub-vectors using values of `x` as grouping keys.
Then `seq` function is called for each group and each result is re-arranged back in the original group position.

Better see an example :

```r
x <- c(5,7,5,5,7,6)
ave(x, x, FUN=seq) # returns 1,1,2,3,2


 ┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
 │ 5 │ 7 │ 5 │ 5 │ 7 │
 └───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘            
   |   |   |    |  |     
   ▼   |   ▼    ▼  |
 GROUP A : seq(c(5,5,5)) = c(1,2,3)
   |   |   |    |  |     
   ▼   |   ▼    ▼  |
 ┌───┐ | ┌───┬───┐ |
 │ 1 │ | │ 2 │ 3 │ |
 └───┘ | └───┴───┘ |
       ▼           ▼
 GROUP B : seq(c(7,7)) = c(1,2)
       |           |
       ▼           ▼
     ┌───┐       ┌───┐
     │ 1 │       │ 2 │
     └───┘       └───┘ 

   |   |   |   |   |
   ▼   ▼   ▼   ▼   ▼ 
 ┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
 │ 1 │ 1 │ 2 │ 3 │ 2 │
 └───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

Note :

`seq(y)` function returns a sequence `1:length(y)` in case `y` has `length(y) > 1`, but returns a sequence from `1:y[1]` if `y` contains only one element.
This is fortunately not a problem because in that case R *- complaining with a lot of  warnings -* selects only the first value which is incidentally what we want :)

Comment: Brilliant! I'll add a bounty for this. Never seen `ave` before.

Comment: I'm honored, thanks a lot ! :)

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 4 bytes

```
&=Rs
```

This solution is 1-based

Try it out at [MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=%26%3DRs&inputs=%5B5%2C12%2C10%2C12%2C12%2C10%5D&version=20.10.0)!

**Explanation**

Uses `[1,2,3,2]` as an example

```
    # Implicitly grab the input array of length N
    #
    #   [1,2,3,2]
    #
&=  # Create an N x N boolean matrix by performing an element-wise comparison
    # between the original array and its transpose:
    #
    #     1 2 3 2
    #     -------
    # 1 | 1 0 0 0
    # 2 | 0 1 0 1
    # 3 | 0 0 1 0
    # 2 | 0 1 0 1
    #
R   # Take the upper-triangular portion of this matrix (sets below-diagonal to 0)
    #
    #   [1 0 0 0
    #    0 1 0 1
    #    0 0 1 0
    #    0 0 0 1]
    #
s   # Compute the sum down the columns
    #
    #   [1,1,1,2]
    #
    # Implicitly display the result
```

Comment: ah, I knew there was an old problem that made me think of something similar, it's Unique is Cheap, and the [MATL solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127290/67312) there is one character different!

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 7 bytes

```
1#.]=]\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYu7CoAwDEX3fsVFBRGkpK1v6J/oJBZxcXD222syREp6T06SK6cnWhAWUHal3eK25sYUFnWKtkaLd0F6jDn280YCVaTYeaVRnjaO4AnhX@vhvEj5BdR7PnKYOCdNHQUWHVePmfXAGYTzBw)

1-indexed.

### Explanation:

```
]\ all the prefixes (filled with zeros, but there won't be any 0s in the input):
   ]\ 5 12 10 12 12 10
5  0  0  0  0  0
5 12  0  0  0  0
5 12 10  0  0  0
5 12 10 12  0  0
5 12 10 12 12  0
5 12 10 12 12 10

]= is each number from the input equal to the prefix:
   (]=]\) 5 12 10 12 12 10
1 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 1 1 0
0 0 1 0 0 1

1#. sum each row:
   (1#.]=]\) 5 12 10 12 12 10
1 1 1 2 3 2
```

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

-1 byte thanks to ngn!

```
{+/'x=,\x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qWltfvcJWJ6ai9n@agpGCuYKhggWQtoDR/wE)

Comment: Heh, you're happy that I made the data strictly positive…

Comment: @Adám Yes, otherwise I'd need to box the prefixes :)

Comment: in k: `='` -> `=`

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 7 bytes

Many, many thanks to H.PWiz, Adám and dzaima for all their help in debugging and correcting this.

```apl
+/¨⊢=,\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X1v/0IpHXYtsdWL@pz1qm/Cob6pXsL/fo44ZGo96@4A8T/9HXc2H1hs/apsI5AUHOQPJEA/PYE2gEqji/2kK6tGx6lwgysQIyjDXAUIo29BAx8hAx9gAyjXVMTTSAYqBSBADKmwE1GGoY6FjBMRQGipjDOSbALGpjiVQ1AxIG4PYseoA)

**Explanation**

The 10-byte non-tacit version will be easier to explain first

```apl
{+/¨⍵=,\⍵}

{         } A user-defined function, a dfn
      ,\⍵  The list of prefixes of our input list ⍵
           (⍵ more generally means the right argument of a dfn)
           \ is 'scan' which both gives us our prefixes 
           and applies ,/ over each prefix, which keeps each prefix as-is
    ⍵=     Checks each element of ⍵ against its corresponding prefix
           This checks each prefix for occurrences of the last element of that prefix
           This gives us several lists of 0s and 1s
 +/¨       This sums over each list of 0s and 1s to give us the enumeration we are looking for
```

The tacit version does three things

- First, it removes the instance of `⍵` used in `,\⍵` as `,\` on the right by itself can implicitly figure out that it's supposed to operate on the right argument.
- Second, for `⍵=`, we replace the `⍵` with `⊢`, which stands for right argument
- Third, now that we have no explicit arguments (in this case, `⍵`), we can remove the braces `{}` as tacit functions do not use them

Answer (score 5):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 14

- 1 byte saved thanks to @NahuelFouilleul

```
{print++a[$1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/uqAoM69EWzsxWsUwtvb/f2MuQy4TIDblsuQy4jID0sYgNgA)

The above does one-based indexing.  If you prefer zero-based indexing, its an extra byte:

```
{print a[$1]++}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/uqAoM69EITFaxTBWW7v2/39jLkMuEyA25bLkMuIyA9LGIDYA)

Comment: note that second can save one byte `{print++a[$1]}` without space seems to be working

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 48 bytes

```python
lambda a:[a[:i].count(v)for i,v in enumerate(a)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU7bDoIwDH33K5b4Akmju4AiiV8y9zAVIokMQoDEr8dWwJQ0W7uey0776V9N0FN5vU1vX9@fXvjceptX7vBohtBHY1w2nahgFFUQRRjqovN9EfnYTW1XhV6UkXWx2Avrjtbtdv9loue1xL3iwBmwFgwUaMJBg@EcJUFLMHKlYf1oWJyWgtKAXLppYHRyRvIiIn/8iUk1plCQIZCtnaslrDpKtrrMb/IykHA3g1CCJ4ULwifshuZtHu68zcbdKef0BQ)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
ηε¤¢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3PZzWw8tObTo//9oYx1DHRMgNtWx1DHSMQPSxiB2LAA)
or as a [Test Suite](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/u9v/c9nNbDy05tOh/rc7/6FiuaBMjIGGuA4RA2tBAx8hAx9gAyDTVMTTSAfJBJIgBFDICqjLUsdAxAmIoDRQ1BrJNgNhUxxIoYgakjUHsWAA)

**Explanation**

```
ηε     # apply to each prefix of the input list
  ¤¢   # count occurrences of the last element
```

Answer (score 4):

## BQN, 1 byte

```
⊒
```

[Try it here!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4oqSCgpGIDPigL8x4oC/NOKAvzHigL814oC/OeKAvzLigL824oC/NeKAvzPigL814oC/OQ==), [All tests](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4oqSCgooRiDigKJKcynCqOKfqAoKCiJbXSIKCiJbNDJdIgoKIls3LDcsN10iCgoiWzEwLDIwLDMwXSIKCiJbNSwxMiwxMCwxMiwxMiwxMF0iCgoiWzIsNywxLDgsMiw4LDEsOCwyLDhdIgoKIlszLDEsNCwxLDUsOSwyLDYsNSwzLDUsOV0iCuKfqQ==)

I don't know much about BQN, but I learned from [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240424/3852) that this is a built-in.

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 44 bytes

```cs
x=>x.Select((y,i)=>x.Take(i).Count(z=>z==y))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpds4@maV5qbWpSYlJNqk5lXYqeDLmCnkKZg@7/C1q5CLzg1JzW5REOjUidTE8QPScxO1cjU1HPOL80r0aiytauyta3U1PxvzRVQBNSqkaaRl1oeHVttrgOEtZqa6OKmOoZGOoYGYBLEACn5DwA)

Comment: [22 bytes](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpds4@mTWVxik5lXYqfj6ZpXmptalJiUkwoWsFNIU7D9X2FrV6EXnJqTmlyiUaHnmZeSWuGfpvnfmiugCKhII00jL7U8OrbaVMfQSMfQAEyCGLWamtb/AQ)

Comment: You have the inversed of the challenge right now.. `[7,7,7]` should output `[0,1,2]`, and not `[0,0,0]`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen - Thanks :) Looks like I misread things, it should be fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 35 bytes

```
->a{f=Hash.new 0;a.map{|v|f[v]+=1}}
```

It's pretty mundane, unfortunately - build a hash that stores the total for each entry encountered so far.

Some other, fun options that unfortunately weren't quite short enough:

```
->a{a.dup.map{a.count a.pop}.reverse}   # 37
->a{i=-1;a.map{|v|a[0..i+=1].count v}}  # 38
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 15 bytes

```perl6
*>>.&{%.{$_}++}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwX8vOTk@tWlWvWiW@Vlu79r81V3FipUKaRnSsJpxpYoTEMdcBQiS@oYGOkYGOsQGSkKmOoZEOUBxEghhIUkZA3YY6FjpGQAylkWSNgWImQGyqYwmUMQPSxiA2UMV/AA)

You can move the `++` to before the `%` for a one based index.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
*>>.&{        }  # Map the input to
      %          # An anonymous hash
       .{$_}     # The current element indexed
            ++   # Incremented
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>47</s> 43 bytes

```python
f=lambda a:a and f(a[:-1])+[a.count(a[-1])]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU5dC8IwDHz3VxR8cRi1H5vOgb@k9KE6hoJ2Q@aDv75e3KYdIU1yuVyve/fXNugYm9PdP861F75Chlo0K2@rjXLZ2vrtpX2FHgDPLnbPW@hBsC4TS2HdzrrFD8v1gErAKsEPhBhXpEjzmjSZhKIkaUlGTizEl4VIWAUpTaDyy03CZl1wxxtWxz//Sw0Likrg5VTTY0nTGduaRIaZpQzliZjBJkcWdMR2j2q4n7tJhefOUnF2GT8)

A recursive 'one-based' solution.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
ċṪ$Ƥ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9I98Odq1SOLfn//3@0qY6hkY6hAZgEMWIB)

For each prefix of the input list, it counts the number of occurrences of its last element in itself.

Comment: Alternatively the old-school `;\ċ"` is also 4.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 41 bytes

```r
function(x)diag(diffinv(outer(x,x,"==")))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7dCsMwCIXv9xSjVwoOEtPuB9qHGWkduVgKoRl5@8xAiuj5PCqYqlznW5Uc/RH2CAXX8P7AGkRC/MGejy1BoULDsgyIWAVi/m4peDCIFwEPI3d4kEZna4gNuXNnIsukXqsNus16YelJrNm1T5z2o@ZEL3Xvqq6xPvAH)

Oddly, returning a zero-based index is shorter in R.

Comment: Once again Giuseppe, your superior knowledge of R has beaten me. I had a decently ingenious method at 60 bytes, but alas, it wasn't enough!

Comment: @Sumner18 post it anyway! I always learn a lot from other peoples' approaches, and getting feedback is the fastest way to learn!

Comment: thanks for the encouragement! I've posted mine now and am always open to suggestions for improvement!

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>62</s> 43 bytes

```r
x=z=scan();for(i in x)z[y]=1:sum(y<-x==i);z
```

-19 bytes thanks to Giuseppe, by removing which, and table, and only slight changes to the implementation

**Original**

```r
x=z=scan();for(i in names(r<-table(x)))z[which(x==i)]=1:r[i];z
```

I can't compete with Giuseppe's knowledge, so my submission is somewhat longer than his, but using my basic knowledge, I felt that this solution was rather ingenious.

`r<-table(x)` counts the number of times each number appears and stores it in r, for future reference

`names()` gets the values of each unique entry in the table, and we iterate over these names with a for loop.

The remaining portion checks which entries are equal to the iterations and stores a sequence of values (from 1 to the number of entries of the iteration)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v8K2yrY4OTFPQ9M6Lb9II1MhM08hLzE3tVijyEa3JDEpJ1WjQlNTsyq6PCMzOUOjwtY2UzPW1tCqKDoz1rrqvymXoRGXoQGYBDH@AwA)

Comment: you can remove the `which()` to save 7 bytes.

Comment: Your use of `1:r[i]` gave me the idea to just remove `table()` entirely: `x=z=scan();for(i in x)z[y]=1:sum(y<-x==i);z` is 43 bytes! This is a nice approach!

Comment: Looks like neither of us can compete with [digEmAll's R knowledge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/178697/67312)!

Comment: I saw that and was absolutely flabbergasted!

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 44 bytes

```hs
([]#)
x#(y:z)=sum[1|a<-x,a==y]:(y:x)#z
_#e=e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU/NToNAEL7zFBPwAOlW@Wm1Nt2TV28e140hdPoTKWB3m1LSsw/gI/og4ixdGpQFZub7G9ik6h3zvF3x19YX0guc2vNP8ybg6rAT0TldjGuWcn6Sc4LrwGucNw85trt0WwCHZekAKPw4YJEhYJ3uqhwVYf7355eQAdzCHtMl8MUC1qifykJjoZXj1ApIAY2ikOqgX/T@uYAbUJvyCMSNRuB2Ate0HXrqUKwrzDQuacVxg3ukCobisCJfNw0k5job@o6bVaRyX7XfC@aD9OayM3CvrlJT/nGr0Lhcx@l/DjhJBAjZfZ@QNDEQk9jOoQUeGJ0eYxGLLR6FLA5ZEl4pOpaasihmxJu3aYYSk8AiK4wpO2IzQmZ9/aM16qhzxCyxnoTmCT1T9kjoPdXE9P92DP12n2xFl3a52bWXP9kqT9eqHWdV9Qs)

### Explanation

Traverses the list from left to right keeping the list `x` of visited elements, initially `[]`:

For every encounter of a `y` count all equal elements in the list `x`.

Comment: A bit longer but maybe nevertheless interesting: `(#(0*));(x:r)#g=g x:r# \y->0^abs(y-x)+g y;e#g=e` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU/NToNAEL7vU0yoB7Bb5afV2nS9ePXmkWKCdEobKSC7TaHx7AP4iD6IOItLg7JhZ@b7mQ@2sXzFLGs3YtXaI/vSdRxm14vKGaUiBWpGsGom9@5z/CLtZlI74xQahsRiu493OQhYFwxA4tsB8wQB63hfZigJs78@PsPIgSuoMF6DWC4hRfVQ5ApzJRmrJZACTpKWlAf1pKrHHC5AbosjEDceg9UJLN12aNOhWJeYKFxTxHGLFVIFTQnYkK@bBhL9vGv6WugoUlkrZfeCxWD76TfTsc6uQtH@406idlmM9T8HgiQhhFH3fWFEE4dw6pvZNcAtp9Nj3OO@wT2X@y4P3DNFx1Az7vmceH3rZijRG7hnhD7t9vickHlf/2i12uscPg@MJ6B5Su@M3xF6QzXQ/b@Mod/kRW0YfSebLE5lO0nK8gc "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: @Laikoni: How did you even come up with that, you should totally post it!

Comment: Done: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/178629/56433

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>47</s> 46 bytes

```hs
(#(*0))
(x:r)#g=g x:r# \y->0^(y-x)^2+g y
e#g=e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU/NToNAEL7vU0yoB7BbhaXV2nS9ePXmkdKE0CltpIDsNoXGsw/gI/og4ixCg7JhZ@b7mQ92kXrFNG22ctXYI/vadRxmV4vSGSUyAWpGsKonj@7aria1sxbjBGqGRGJziPYZSNjkDEDh2xGzGAGr6FCkqAizvz4@g9CBGygx2oBcLiFB/ZRnGjOtGKsUkALOipYUR/2iy@cMrkDt8hMQNx6D1Qos07Zo3aJYFRhr3FDEaYclUgVDSdiSr50GEvO8G/pWmihSWStt94LFYPv5N9OxLq5c0/7TXqFxWYz1PweSJAEEYft9QUgTh2AqutntgHtOp8e4x0WHey4XLvfdC0Wno2bcE5x4c5tmKDEbuNcJBe32@JyQeV//aI3aax2C@53Hp3lK74w/EHpH1Tf9v4yhv8sLmyD8jrdplKhmEhfFDw)

A different approach than [BMO's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/178549/56433) which turned out a bit longer. (And kindly borrows their nice test suit.)

The idea is to iterate over the input list and keep track of the number of times each element has occurred by updating a function `g`. Ungolfed:

```hs
f (const 0)
f g (x:r) = g x : f (\ y -> if x==y then 1 + g y else g y) r
f g []    = []
```

Two interesting golfing opportunities arose. First for the initial value of `g`, a constant function which disregards its argument and returns `0`:

```hs
const 0  -- the idiomatic way
(\_->0)  -- can be shorter if parenthesis are not needed
min 0    -- only works as inputs are guaranteed to be non-negative
(0*)     -- obvious in hindsight but took me a while to think of
```

And secondly an expression over variables `x` and `y` which yields `1` if `x` equals `y` and `0` otherwise:

```hs
if x==y then 1else 0  -- yes you don't need a space after the 1
fromEnum$x==y         -- works because Bool is an instance of Enum
sum[1|x==y]           -- uses that the sum of an empty list is zero
0^abs(x-y)            -- uses that 0^0=1 and 0^x=0 for any positive x
0^(x-y)^2             -- Thanks to  Christian Sievers!
```

There still might be shorter ways. Anyone got an idea?

Comment: You can use `0^(x-y)^2`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 76 bytes

```java
a->{for(int l=a.length,i,c;l-->0;a[l]=c)for(c=i=0;i<l;)c+=a[l]==a[i++]?1:0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVFdT4MwFH3fr7ghMQFXCB9T5zowxmeffCQ81A5mZymkLTPLwm/HUpySGGPS3p6ec3pvb3sgR@Ifdu8Dq9tGajiYfdBpxoNrvPjFVZ2gmjViFCknSsEzYQLOC4C2e@WMgtJEm@XYsB3URnNftGRinxdA5F551grw1AjV1aXcMqHzIoMK0oH42blqpGso4CkJeCn2@g0xRDH3/SzEJOdFSr3RQ1OWhphtOfboMrWCiWy5LB6iTYj7AdsyRyJBl0orSEGUH2Cr5cV0B4Az9OgbruL57g7ZMaeiEEFsZhLO2RsEUYysaFeL54bYZooQrNGI13M89yVWWNlokt5bx63FycRc3P3UnA3jY1y63Ey9Xt4Y4OWkdFkHTaeD1nyCrlznyk9CBX4GDoJHKclJBbqZvsgdT3uBLFtOaOk6xuI4noe/klUBobRs9WTDf5Tgwv0/Lfzk7Rfj7IdP)

### Credits

- -2 bytes thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)

Comment: -2 bytes by changing `for(c=0,i=l;i-->0;)c+=a[l]==a[i]?1:0;` to `for(c=i=0;i<l;)c+=a[l]==a[i++]?1:0;`.

Answer (score 1):

## bash, <s>37</s> 24 bytes

```
f()(for x;{ r+=$[a[x]++]\ ;};echo $r)
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##NYo7CoAwEER7TzGFhZImH78ET6IWKgY7ITaCePY4W8iy894Ouy7XkVIoyiKcEbd/ENWQj8t4z0rNE/zr9@04kccyhSygsoxWhjQaVsNpag1j5ZYUYWX5ZdCR3U@2jl5xa/RsGtKJpw8)

if valid, there is also this variation, as suggested by DigitalTrauma

```
for x;{ echo $[a[x]++];}
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Py2/SKHCuporNTkjX0ElOjG6IlZbO5ar9v///8b/Df@bALHpf8v/Rv/NgLQxiA0A)

Comment: Pass the list as command line args - https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Py2/SKHCuporNTkjX0ElOjG6IlZbO5ar9v///8b/Df@bALHpf8v/Rv/NgLQxiA0A - only 24 bytes.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma, thanks however i don't know if it broke the rules. also as it was asked to replace list and maybe should be something like https://tio.run/##NUtLCoMwFNz3FFPJIkEKJtrWEgIuvUPIIpWKBVGILoSQs9skUB7z5sPM227TeY6UefSKMjmvg51xW@AU4RLj6nDgu4D4q9OdCdLD6cMoonudhClLI4MM577tlMHDKko6FpewEp9hWlEQb9O0kAiXWEtAIzI902XFK4gKdZXNHVykJP0kcihil6ON3P4553V0TcQdr5g9ItdJnz8

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul It's fine, full programs are allowed too, and that's a valid method of inputting/outputting a list (IMO)

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 48 bytes

```
proc C L {lmap n $L {dict g [dict inc D $n] $n}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7NCsIwEITveYo59AGSTevPuR59g7YHiSCFGoPGU9hnj5Miy@x8OwwkOWy1pvcrYMQVZXveEiI64n0NGQ9Mu68x4IIuLpRq3WvsmKKm9MJ1BIfuLMTCW@IAJ@DddgNGwpbDCUL9nakn99SAM5MD3TdWGEVJ3/zBXKaRn1pmvv0D)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 34 bytes

```ruby
->a{r=[];a.map{|x|(r<<x).count x}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6xusg2OtY6US83saC6pqJGo8jGpkJTLzm/NK9EoaK29n@BQlp0dGwsF5g2MYKxzHWAEMYxNNAxMtAxNoDxTXUMjXSAgiASxICJGwE1GepY6BgBMZSGSRkDBUyA2FTHEihsBqSNQezY2P8A)

Comment: I can't believe I tried `->a{i=-1;a.map{|v|a[0..i+=1].count v}}` and didn't think of just building a new array, lol. Nice work.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 11 bytes

```
$_=$h{$_}++
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lYlo1olvlZb@/9/Yy5DLhMgNuWy5DLiMgPSxiD2v/yCksz8vOL/ugU5AA)

explanations following comment

- `$_` perl's  special variable containing current line when looping over input (`-p` or `-n` switches)
- `$h{$_}++` autovivifies the map `%h` and creates an entry with key `$_` and increments and gives the value before increment
- the special variable is printed because of `-p` switch, `-l` switch removes end of line on input and adds end of line on output

Comment: That looks amazing. Care to explain?

Comment: @Adám, thank you for your feedback, sure, done

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>65</s> 62 bytes

```c
c,d;f(a,b)int*a;{for(;c=d=b--;a[b]=d)for(;c--;d-=a[c]!=a[b]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JUtLCsIwEN33FLUgZGwCrWA345wkZDGdUJmFVYq7kLPHRDfv/8Q9RMqTdTeQOt0/PftA6Wbnq52nHzaRsdsM2wUqvw7TdkoT6n1BHUd4HzXZzHCO/WDZa6i7XMRGbK8VanthTO2KQpFW55D9GijCP6s@OmIv4UStAMylfAE)

-2 bytes thanks to [ASCII-only](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/178500/enumerate-each-series-of-identical-numbers-in-place/178724?noredirect=1#comment430784_178724)

---

This felt too straightforward, but I couldn't seem to get any shorter with a different approach.

Comment: [63](https://tio.run/##HUs7CsMwDN1zijRQsBobkkLJoOokxoMsk6KhaQjdgs/u2l3e/4l7iZQ362bg7HT79uwDnQ873@08/bGJjN1q2C5Q@XOYtlOaUJ8L6jjCftRkNcM19YNlr6HuchGbsL0i1PbGeLYrRueQfQyUoPlEQhGlhskRewkXai1gLuUH)

Comment: @ASCII-only is this a valid answer? No header included, no declarations, it's a snippet plus many warnings although it outputs.

Comment: @AZTECCO warnings are fine (stderr is ignored), as long as it does what it should it's acceptable. note that this _is_ a function declaration, plus some variable declarations - you can put it anywhere as a top level expression and it will compile fine. a lot of c answers (and those in languages with less strict syntax) _do_ generally have quite a few warnings because of bytesaves that aren't good code style

Comment: Ok I can understand, but there's still something not right to me. If we want to test with a different set(in size) we have to modify the code, even in the print loop, plus the input should be just the set, not its size."Given a list of strictly positive integers..." so I think input should be just the list.

Comment: @AZTECCO not sure if this discussion should belong in this answer's comments, but you might want to take a look at [meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions) - specifically on [I/O](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13262/81203) and [answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2422/81203) formats.

Comment: Ok thank you both two for helping me understand the rules here at codegolf. Short solution btw!+1

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 32 bytes

```
a->p=0;[polcoeff(p+=x^t,t)|t<-a]
```

The \$k\$-th element in the answer is the coefficient of the \$x^{a_k}\$ term in the polynomial \$\sum_{i=1}^kx^{a_i}\$.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYrbCsIwEER/JfQpwQ3k0npB0x8pERYxUijtUvKg4L/HXZBlZs4MS7jP9kWtqNTQjpTcdaJteWzPUjQd0vteoZpvvVnMDYmWj0ZlR0X7vFbGTkqnikZjQE1TZuuD@An4BLyD4CA64QF8AB7EBWQL/OjhDIH1T5kjl541wIWnI2cUztm0Hw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 21 bytes (@att)

```
_g=g/@#-(--g[#]&/@#)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYpLCsMwDESvIjCYFmTiT9LPIiVH6D6EYkrjZpEuinfGZ3dHUMSMnh7aY36/9pi3Z2wrje2RxtRNyhyMSbNaNPio2/27ffKsyNxohV1IUzdRKZWp9F76zBgBZ9lbDlZ4YOcZQlpAnMej4wt75L9FBxw9MvAV6oQdhGttPw)

---

### [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 28 bytes

```
(Clear@g;g@a_=0;++g[#]&/@#)&
```

Based on [@att's answer to another challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240467/9288).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYrdCsIwDEZfJVAoyiLrzzaVMSn4At6PIUW2OnBejN6VPntNQML35eSQzcf3vPm4vnxZYCiH@2f2uwt9cP45qL6qwigmWTtxlOWxr984CjjdYCE7gYTaQUoZITWG@4w0DFqhUWgVc4vaIAluBnaGHjVe0FD@m7Wlo6G0eCXV0bbMOZcf)

---

### [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 32 bytes

-1 byte thanks to @att.

```
Accumulate[p=x^#]~Coefficient~p&
```

The \$k\$-th element in the answer is the coefficient of the \$x^{a_k}\$ term in the polynomial \$\sum_{i=1}^kx^{a_i}\$.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYrdCsIwDEZfJTDYVcS13fy5mCi@gPdjQiktFtY5pAOhdK9eE5DwfTk5JOj4skFHb3Rx0JebMWtYJx3tsPTfZzVu97d1zhtv57gtdXl8/ByHCnYXcEM1jlDD/gopZYTUSu4j0jCIBmWDqmHuUEgkwc3ATtKjwBNKyn@zVnS0lA7PpA60FXPO5Qc)

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##LYrdCsIwDEZfJTDYVcS13fy5mCi@gPdjQiktFtY5pAOhdK9eE5DwfTk5JOj4skFHb3Rx0JebMWtYJx3tsPTfZzVu97d1zhtv57gtdXl8/ByHCnYXcEM1jlDD/gopZYTUSu4j0jCIBmWDqmHuUEgkwc3ATtKjwBNKyn@zVnS0lA7PpA60FXPO5Qc) on the first, and [-2 bytes](https://tio.run/##LYrdCsIwDEZfJVAoyiLrzzaVMSn4At6PIUW2OnBejN6VPntNQML35eSQzcf3vPm4vnxZYCiH@2f2uwv9Mwyqr6owiknWThxleezrN44CTjdYyE4goXaQUkZIjeE@Iw2DVmgUWsXcojZIgpuBnaFHjRc0lP9mbeloKC1eSXW0LXPO5Qc) on the second

Comment: Roman had a good [insight](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241591/how-many-times-can-i-skip-a-stone/241622?noredirect=1#comment544913_241622) that saves [-2 bytes](https://tio.run/##LYrdCsIwDEZfJVAoyiLrz6aTUekjeD@GFHHdLubF6F3ps9cEJHxfTg7ZQ1o/e0jbO9QFXD1Ft3oxvqJTY9PEScyy9eIs6/PYvmkScHnAQnYGCa2HnAtC7gz3DWkYtEKj0CrmHrVBEtwM7Aw9ahzQUP6btaWjo/R4J3WlbZlLqT8) on the second, and probably all other answers that used `Clear` as well.

Comment: I just realized that this specific golf isn't actually valid here (nor on your AoCG17; I'm not sure about your AoCG16), since the function won't be reusable on the same input. Sorry about that, I jumped the gun.

Comment: [24](https://tio.run/##LYq9CsMwDIRfRSAwCVGJLSf9GVL8CN1DBlOaNEM6FG/Gz@5KUMTdfTruiOn9OmLan7GuMNVtxqXrTB8abLaAk2uFsTX18d0/aUY43WGVzQIG@gA5F4I8sPqF5BScJbbkrfJIjkkKdQXtWIaOrsSif2rt5RlEI92kOkt65VLqDw) on the second

Comment: `_g=0Clear@g` could've saved 1 otherwise

Comment: [21](https://tio.run/##LYpLCsMwDESvIjCYFmTiT9LPIiVH6D6EYkrjZpEuinfGZ3dHUMSMnh7aY36/9pi3Z2wrje2RxtRNyhyMSbNaNPio2/27ffKsyNxohV1IUzdRKZWp9F76zBgBZ9lbDlZ4YOcZQlpAnMej4wt75L9FBxw9MvAV6oQdhGttPw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 23 bytes

```
{`~&>Zip[_,_[0:#_::0]]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYs7C0IxDIX3/oqC4pShj3t9FHRxFwcnS6jl2qt3kWK7if71mqJNSM45X4jP2Q/3UEZutry8Lp/F7jxF68BZYWbOGIH4LocQrsnOYxxuyI7P6ZFPIeW9TyHZEbhlnMoi/LRTza2AugUpQAnQouUepAKCdVfTuKInCWtQNH9tJ02go@lhQ3hJqqtHhli@)

### Explanation

```
{`~&>Zip[_,_[0:#_::0]]}
{                     }    _: input (e.g., [5, 12, 10, 12, 12, 10])
             0:#_          range from 0 to length of input (inclusive)
                           e.g., [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
                 ::0       descending range down to 0 for each element
                           e.g., [[0], [1, 0], [2, 1, 0], [3, 2, 1, 0], [4, 3, 2, 1, 0], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]]
           _[       ]      get input elements at those indices
                           e.g., [[5], [12, 5], [10, 12, 5], [12, 10, 12, 5], [12, 12, 10, 12, 5], [10, 12, 12, 10, 12, 5], [nil, 10, 12, 12, 10, 12, 5]]
     Zip[_,          ]     concatenate each value with this array
                           e.g., [[5, [5]], [12, [12, 5]], [10, [10, 12, 5]], [12, [12, 10, 12, 5]], [12, [12, 12, 10, 12, 5]], [10, [10, 12, 12, 10, 12, 5]]]
   &>                      using each sub-array spread as arguments...
 `~                            count frequency
                               e.g. [12, [12, 10, 12, 5]] = 12 ~ [12, 10, 12, 5] = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), 18 bytes

```
(,/.!'#'=x)@<,/.=x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7X2FlrGCoYALEpgqWCkYKZkDaGMT@r6Gjr6eorqxuW6HpYANk21b8/w8A)

---

**OLD APPROACH**

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), <s>27 23</s> 22 bytes

```
{x[,/.=x]:,/.!'#'=x;x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqroiWkdfz7Yi1gpIKaorq9tWWFfU/k9TMFYwVDABYlMFSwUjBTMgbQxi/wcA)

---

this is not pretty... quick and dirty solution, i will be refining this later when i get the chance to think of a better approach

explanation:

- `=x` returns a dict where keys are items of x and values are their indices (`3 1 4 5 9 2 6!(0 9;1 3;,2;4 8 10;5 11;,6;,7)`)
- `i:` assign dict to `i`
- `#:'` count values for each key (`3 1 4 5 9 2 6!2 2 1 3 2 1 1`)
- `!:'` enumerate each value (`3 1 4 5 9 2 6!(0 1;0 1;,0;0 1 2;0 1;,0;,0)`)
- `,/.:` extract values and flatten list (`0 1 0 1 0 0 1 2 0 1 0 0`)
- `x[,/.:i]:` extract indices from i, flatten, and assign each value from the right-side list at these indices

annoyingly, the list is updated but a null value is returned by the assignment, so i need to return the list after the semicolon (`;x`)

**edit:** removed extraneous colons

**edit2:** removed unnecessary assignment

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
KƛtO
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJLxpt0TyIsIiIsIls1LDEyLDEwLDEyLDEyLDEwXSJd)

`KƛṫO` is also valid for 4 bytes

Simply count the number of occurrences of the tail of each prefix in each prefix.

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 48 bytes

```
[ dup [ head [ = ] with count ] with map-index ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5BDoJADEX3c4p/AQ0MoKhxbdy4Ma4ICwI1EHUYhyFqCGcfCwHatO/3N016z3JbG3e7ni@nPR5kFD3R0LsllVMDbcjanzaVsjgI0QlwdOgnhnKR2zHnyfcgPQTeYkTw5eAOfRTzQvKVj5gZL5x3ATshV4Qd@xtmMOpe9C5B0WokKCkrGEek@FS2RF63/Os0vDK9qlRBX6SONdbuDw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
z#ḣ¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/v0r54Y7Fh3b@//8/2lTH0EjH0ABMghixAA)

#### Explanation

one-indexed

```
z#ḣ¹  transforms to z#ḣ⁰⁰
z     zip
  ḣ⁰  prefixes of input
    ⁰ and input
 #    with count
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 25 bytes

```powershell
$t=@{}
$args|%{(++$t.$_)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5vS8MwEMbf91OEEl3LrtKmnU6kUBn6SlCc70RGrZnbqHY2KQpdP3u9NHSJ5si/e353z@2rb16LDS/LoKhq3tN12vZUplnbOTSv38XhpPWmUyrP6Mrv@s5xMs8huCDzMs8H4rq@@SdMZSI7dQEYQxYYxLYShcBCiEMtYtjiDCIGSKhTPY6Q6gLMRhk6RDBHYT7ehlY8G2piSOyqGKUE9wwuUT7HO1Zv28fuoD19ciC3VX2TF5vg/nXHC0naoSWVXMhFLjgQyn/2KPA3khK60mrNRVPKa3G3FRLTp3RNsrHCJlTJHzbYVdtPMoGJM2DPD8tFI2T1oc1fMu2u1rIpCi6E6UAC/mWGuTqC7hMaE@XsKngcw1gZ9PHfUFrpnK7/BQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 30 bytes

```
\b(\d+)\b(?<=(\b\1\b.*?)+)
$#2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYlLCoAwDET3uYYurA3SpvUHihfJxqILNy7E@9cpSJh5b8hzvte956yp0cMaYFvWRpN6TV27GWuoriRnikIj48g7FsfBUc9eGKt0ERL8PU8syE8KsIj0PGMPYCj@AQ) Link includes test cases. 1-indexed. Explanation: The first part of the regex matches each integer in the list in turn. The lookbehind's group matches each occurrence of that integer on that line up to and including the current integer. The integer is then substituted with the number of matches.

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 61 bytes

```
@setlocal
@for %%n in (%*)do @set/ac=c%%n+=1&call echo %%c%%
```

1-indexed. Because variable substitution happens before parsing, the `set/a` command ends up incrementing the variable name given by concatenating the letter `c` with the integer from the list (numeric variables default to zero in Batch). The result is then copied to another integer for ease of output (more precisely, it saves a byte).

Answer (score 0):

## Japt, 8 bytes

```
£¯YÄ è¶X
```

[Try it here](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=o69ZxCDotlg=&input=WzMsMSw0LDEsNSw5LDIsNiw1LDMsNSw5XQ==)

```
£¯YÄ è¶X
             :Implicit input of array U
£            :Map each X at 0-based index Y
 ¯           :  Slice U to index
  YÄ         :    Y+1
     è       :  Count the elements
      ¶X     :    Equal to X
```

Answer (score 0):

## awk <s>46</s> 31 bytes

-15 bytes thanks to @Dennis

```
{for(;i++<NF;)$i=a[$i]++;print}
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##SyzP/l@dkpqTWpKqkahpnWlrUPu/Oi2/SMM6U1vbxs/NWlMl0zYxWiUzVlvbuqAoM6@k9v9/LhMjLnMFIOQyNFAwMlAwNuAyVTA0UgDyQCSIwWUElDdUsFAwAmIozWUMZJkAsamCJZBvBqSNQWwA)

Comment: I think `{for(;i++<NF;)$i=a[$i]++;print}` works. `delete(a);` is only needed for the test suite, no?

Comment: @Dennis, thank you for your feedback, however DigitalTrauma's version is still shorter

Answer (score 0):

## Haxe, 58 bytes

```
l->{var x=[0=>0];l.map(e->++x[(x[e]==null?x[e]=0:0)+e]);};
```

(Requires arrow functions, so 4.0+)

`var x=[0=>0]` declares a new `IntMap`, with `0` as its only key (since the question say inputs are strictly positive). Unfortunately most targets throw when adding `null` to a number, hence the explicit check to make sure each key is in the map before incrementing.

Also a cheeky rip off based on the JS answer:

## Haxe (JS target), 41 bytes

```
l->{var x=[0=>0];l.map(e->x[e]=-~x[e]);};
```

[Try both online](http://try-haxe.mrcdk.com/#485c4)

Answer (score 0):

**GO 121 Bytes (Not included new lines and tabs)**

```
func cg(a []int) []int{
    var m = make(map[int]int)
    var r = make([]int, len(a))
    for i,v := range a{
        r[i] = m[v]
        m[v]++
    }
    return r
}
```

Accepts integer array and returns integer array.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG. Rare to see Go represented here. You do need to count necessary newlines, but you also have a lot of spaces that can be removed, and you can also shorten `cg` to `c`. I recommend using TIO to generate the main part of your post: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBNCoMwEIXXzSlCV5EORaP9Be/QvbgYRCW0iTJYN@LZ7STtsiHMzOO9LwlMP2wjNk/sW2nROGHsONAk952d9qJ7uybYKpGL2LF3fJBx08upRlU1q2VNkv9BoaPRBfhE0ywFnUKeRoETZBqY8t2LKKj5nwyuoLl@M8rmTBRcJ7gxd@aZe@35dQt7aBQGNPlemJGkLS0@W2VxrNgKofA@ff0Awqt1CvmZbiBpYL6XhI63jQtVpi5tNdfCt8NhFdROb3KS1m37AA "Go – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 44 bytes

```python
a=[]
for x in input():print a.count(x);a+=x,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9E2OpYrLb9IoUIhMw@ICkpLNDStCooy80oUEvWS80vzSjQqNK0TtW0rdP7/jzbWMdQxAWJTHUsdIx0zIG0MYscCAA)

The first thing I wrote tied Chas Brown's 43, so here's a different solution that's one byte longer.

Answer (score 0):

## [Reticular](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/reticular), 17 bytes

```
L[ddc@c~]~*$qlbo;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otyUwuzUks@v/fJzolJdkhuS62TkulMCfJ3/r/fwA)

The input list of integers is assumed to already be pushed to the stack. Run the following code to test input:

```
'2''7''1''8''2''8''1''8''2''8'lbL[ddc@c~]~*$qlbo;
```

### Explanation

The pop instruction `c` which is supposed to: pop a list from the stack, pop the last element from that list and push this element to the stack. However, if the list occurs at more than 1 place in the stack (if it has been duplicated for example), **all of the duplicated lists** in the stack will also have their last element popped contrary to what one might think will happen. This is fortunately used in our favor in this puzzle.

```
L                 # Push length of input list to the stack.
 [      ]         # Push the following function:
  dd              # Duplicate top of stack twice.
    c             # Pop the list at top of the stack,
                    pop the last element in the list (which will pop the element of every list!)
                    and finally push it to the stack.
     @c           # Pop two items at the top of the stack (list + last element in that list).
                    then push the number of occurrences of that element in the list.
       ~          # Swap top two items in the stack (so that the popped list is on top again).
         ~        # Swap top two items in the stack.
          *       # Call the above function the same number of times as length of the input list.
           $      # Remove the item at the top of the stack (which by now is an empty list).
            q     # Reverse stack.
             lb   # Push size of stack and put that many items from the stack into a list.
               o; # Output resulting list and exit.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 63 bytes

```
 T =TABLE()
R I =INPUT :F(END)
 T<I> =OUTPUT =T<I> + 1 :(R)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/XyFEwTbE0cnHVUOTK0jBU8HW0y8gNETByk3D1c9Fk0shxMbTTsHWPzQEJGoL5mkrGCpYaQRpcgFV/P9vyGXIZcRlzGUCAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 122 bytes

```cpp
#import<vector>
using V=std::vector<int>;V f(V x){for(int i,t,z=x.size();t=i=z--;x[z]=t)for(;i--;)t-=x[z]!=x[i];return x;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZLrboIwFID/8xToEoFYDHecLTwGf5xZGIJpNi6BujAbnt2dioimIe1pv/PR0zbNmsY8Zdn1@kbLpm4Z@c0zVrexcu5odVKTqGPH3W6EhFYsxola6InaG7yoWx2IShFDl6jfdPSS6wZmEY0upon7/eUQMUNYmMLcYGYk2AJ6esBtzs5tpfZ4eJSmdcfaPC1j5Vb0PlvVTd6mojzRX/gYUFZXHVOT1TFlqcFHSIi21zAt9IWgm7xs2J9uPG05sjAlt9y4a9PG05@C7ul6fYBFkGa88M1Xmn3DGYf77h/VDhoelETp0rL5yT8tbiMHuciD5gxowvZj5HDvibs8RPDNwOO2hRwLudbMfO4j20GQEL0YzLmAO7CAjbZQdTvFOR1yF6AHzUfvkAogumI8YKVMaaWLa4OLzeozUwiZDkHIMoqXhBT6RAw46UelzY4tObbkOJLjSI4rOa7keJLjSY4vOb7kBJITSE4oOeHdgef6Dw)

Saved 2 more bytes thanks to @ceilingcat

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 172 bytes

Without LINQ.  `0` indexed `int[]` arrays.

```cs
p=>{int h=0,m=0,l=p.Length,j;var k=new int[l];if(l>0){foreach(int z in p){h=z>h?z:h;m=z<m?z:m;}for(j=m;j<=h;j++,m=0)for(int z=0;z<l;z++)k[z]=p[z]==j?m++:k[z];}return k;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZBLb4MwDIDv/AqrJyKyitJ2j4bQw6SdNmnSDjt0HBhNC5QExKPTgvjtzEGddpm0w4QsP2LH/izH9VVcVGJo61Qd4eWzboRkVpxHdQ3PVXGsItlZAGX7nqcx1E3UoDsX6R6eolTZxBQBHloV@6lqdiGF0QWwBz6UPOjwCQl3qUTNeTl/FOrYJDRj56iCE1fiY@zIQ5Ye7DxwSXfAfaI4sU2nxiKUpEu4DpKt3iRMcu1LjCTr8aOdcckynycscxzDICY5dnKXaT9n2nHIaadDXhrDs610nI1JsL4STVspOLHesqyBWRcw/JD39vd@IXQ9IZcDze8LVRe5mL9WaSNsDQ7MYEbYr9XZm8LSX8NX3qTjbyjKpISFSz2XLt1JIWu68CiSjDXBpDAPb7agt9RDvfhJeUukrFDX9A5Z1@iXJv4fs0cZvgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 7 bytes

```
.e/<Qkb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Xy9V3yYwO@n//2hTHUMjHUMDMAlixAIA)

```
.e     Q # enumerated map over (implicit) Q (input): lambda k,b: (k=index, b=element)
  /   b  # number of occurences of b in
   <Qk   # Q[:k]
```

### Alternative 1-based solution (7 bytes)

```
m/ded._
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P1c/JTVFL/7//2hTHUMjHUMDMAlixAIA)

```
m    ._ # map over all prefixes of (implicit) Q (input): lambda d:
 / ed   # Number of occurences of d[-1] in
  d     #                                  d
```

Answer (score 0):

## [SAP ABAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABAP), 174 bytes

```
FORM f TABLES t.DATA r TYPE int_tab1.LOOP AT t.DATA(i) = 0.DATA(x) = sy-tabix.LOOP AT t.CHECK:sy-tabix < x,t = t[ x ].i = i + 1.ENDLOOP.APPEND i TO r.ENDLOOP.t[] = r.ENDFORM.
```

Subroutine which takes a table of integers and replaces all values with zero-based indices. ABAP has no array type, so a table of integers is the closest thing we have. It uses the builtin table type `int_tab1` to save some bytes over declaring `TYPE TABLE OF i` and abuses obsolete (but still functional) internal tables with header lines, which allows us to use `LOOP AT t` and read `t` at the implicit index `sy-tabix` without declaring additional variables for keeping the value.

---

Full program with some test cases from OP [can be found here](https://pastebin.com/0Z4WWUwM). Output below:
[image: Results from the test cases]

Forgot to add the two edge cases of `[ ]` and `[42]`, but they work, too:
`[ ]` => An empty input table stays empty as the outer loop gets skipped completely
`[42]` => A single value in the table means table line 1 in the inner loop is skipped, since `sy-tabix` is equal to `x` - therefore `i` stays `0` and the output is `[0]`.

---

#### Explanation:

```
FORM f TABLES t.              "Subroutine, TABLES parameters are references
  DATA r TYPE int_tab1.       "A temporary internal table for results
  LOOP AT t.                  "Go over each line in table t
    DATA(i) = 0.              "Set count to 0            (inline declaration)
    DATA(x) = sy-tabix.       "Set x to current index    (inline declaration)
    LOOP AT t.                "Go over each line in table t again
      CHECK:                  "Check whether... (works like a CONTINUE if not true)
        sy-tabix < x,         "1) ...inner LOOP index is smaller than outer index (= only check lines up to outer index - 1)
        t = t[ x ].           "2) ...value of t at inner index (implicit) is equal to value of t at outer index (x)
      i = i + 1.              "If both are true, increase the counter by 1
    ENDLOOP.                  
    APPEND i TO r.            "Add the count for this value to temporary results table
  ENDLOOP.                    
  t[] = r.                    "Fill referenced table t with the values in r.
ENDFORM.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 32 characters

```
<D>=@set{$1;@add{${$1;};1}}${$1}
```

Outputs 1 based indexes.

Sample run:

```
bash-5.0$ gema '<D>=@set{$1;@add{${$1;};1}}${$1}' <<< '[5,12,10,12,12,10]'
[1,1,1,2,3,2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU9BbsMgELz7FRspRw6Ak7YRbeVDpSpvSHJY2ZsYCWMLcC8Wb3eWJIcK7cwwml2WGw24rp8/319NpLRslWmw65ZtUdmonIvK6wZ@OQhTGFuKkSKknoB8soHA@mlOjIAQrb85gjD7agMY4ciZeaCAiTpA5yDiMDlu/59@9Avo8Y8gjRCIF3nMb8fZJwoR8MoEhG3/esxZT9XZP3e2RuYm0ESYFiWlNM@fWJMb69uw2JzPfj1dqtNOM7wLPsxKCi1FLVnuhdKC7wWLYEtzSokPoblezG7Nese1Fwd23pjroi93)

### Gema, 34 characters

```
<D>=${$1;0}@set{$1;@add{${$1;};1}}
```

Outputs 0 based indexes.

Sample run:

```
bash-5.0$ gema '<D>=${$1;0}@set{$1;@add{${$1;};1}}' <<< '[5,12,10,12,12,10]'
[0,0,0,1,2,1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU9BbsMgELz7FRspRw6Ak7SVmyqHSlHekOSwsrcxEsYW4F4s3u4sNIcK7c4wml2GBw24rp/fX8ftslWNTKdAMbMTdt1StNSolNYNnNkKkx9bCoECxJ6AXDSewLhpjtwBIRj3sAR@dtUGMMCFPfNAHiN1gNZCwGGyPP7fXeYF9PhLEEfwxBnK/nacXSQfAH8YgLDtX49Z46i6uWOJa3JuTxNhXJSUsvn7RJGNa/1iUrq59XqvrjvN7U3wYVRSaClqyXQvlBZ8zz0TljS7lHgXmuuFrNbMd1x78cHKgbHO/P4E)

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev/doc/), 85 bytes

```go
package main
func main(){
m:=make(map[int]int)
for i,n:=range a{
a[i]=m[n]
m[n]++
}
}
```

Create a map to store the count, loop through input list (a), replacing each item with the count for that item before incrementing.

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)], 13 bytes

```apl
(+/⊃⍷⊢)⍤⌽¨,\⎕
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ƒıṪc
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDNiU5MiVDNCVCMSVFMSVCOSVBQWMmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0lNUIzJTJDMSUyQzQlMkMxJTJDNSUyQzklMkMyJTJDNiUyQzUlMkMzJTJDNSUyQzklNUQmZmxhZ3M9)

##### Explanation

```python
ƒıṪc­⁡​‎‎  # Implicit input⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
ƒ     # ‎⁡Get the prefixes of the input list
 ı    # ‎⁢Map over this list of lists:
  Ṫ   # ‎⁣ Remove the last item and push it separately
   c  # ‎⁤ Count the occurrences of this letter
      # ‎⁢⁡Implicit output
```